# How do I update Node.js?

Tags: node.js, software-update

I did the following to update my npm:

```
npm update npm -g
```

But I have no idea how to update Node.js. Any suggestions? (I'm using Node.js 0.4.1 and want to update to Node.js 0.6.1.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I update NodeJS and Npm for the next versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6237295) .

(should at the very least be linked)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading Node.js to latest version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version)

Comment: I don't really get why most of the answers suggest to install third party tools :/

Comment: Things have gotten quite a bit easier since this question was first answered (if you don't need version management) : [All platforms (Windows, Mac & Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010229/2768271)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Answer (score 720, accepted):

Use [Node Version Manager (NVM)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

It's a Bash script that lets you download and manage different versions of node. Full source code is [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/nvm.sh).

There is a separate project for nvm for Windows: [github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Below are the full steps to use NVM for multiple version of node on windows

1. download [nvm-setup.zip](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.7/nvm-setup.zip) extract and install it.
2. execute command `nvm list available` from cmd or gitbash or powershell, this will list all available version of node [image]
3. use command `nvm install version`  e.g. `nvm install 12.14.0` to install on the machine
4. last once installed use `nvm use version` to use newer version e.g. `nvm use 12.14.0`

Comment: FYI, the command to run once having install NVM is 
'nvm install <version>'. For example 'nvm install v0.8.7'

Comment: FYI: I even used nvm on an (arm) android tablet with debian. It downloads src & builds it. I upgraded v0.6.x to v0.8.x without issue.

Comment: You don't need this. Node is not Ruby.

Comment: I really liked NVM before iojs and npm agreed to merge back together. But now it's just a hassle for little reward. Anything that thinks it knows where your node path will be automatically will need to be configured manually. Not a huge deal but kind of annoying.

Comment: @SimonEast There is an nvm for windows: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: @PhilHannent as per NVM github page, they don't support NVM on windows, so one can say that "there is no official NVM for windows"

Comment: For windows just download latest version and install it. It will be automatically updated to new version you downloaded.

Comment: https://michael-kuehnel.de/node.js/2015/09/08/using-vm-to-switch-node-versions.html this is a good documentation for nvm use

Comment: If you're using VS Code, don't forget to restart it after installing NVM

Comment: you just want to install latest version of NodeJs from official site and it will automatically be updated. WHY BOTHER WITH NVM?

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it led me down the right road. A couple of notes, it works better if you uninstall node if you have installed it previously, just know you will have to reinstall Angular CLI if you had it installed.

Comment: now the list command is `nvm ls-remote`

Comment: If you want latest version just run `nvm install node`."node" is an alias for the latest version

Answer (score 1758):

To upgrade Node you may first want to see which version of Node.js you are currently using:

```
node --version
```

Find out which versions of Node.js you may have installed and which one of those you're currently using:

```
nvm ls
```

List all versions of Node.js available for installation:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

[Apparently for Windows](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/) the command would be rather like this:

```
nvm ls available
```

Assuming you would pick Node.js v8.1.0 for installation you'd type the following to install that version:

```
nvm install 8.1.0
```

You are then free to choose between installed versions of Node.js. So if you would need to use an older version like v4.2.0 you would set it as the active version like this:

```
nvm use 4.2
```

That should be all.

---

In 2013 I used the following instructions to upgrade from Node.js version 0.10.6 to 0.10.21 on a Mac, for more recent instructions see above.

Update from 2017: Please mind, Mr. Walsh himself recommended to [update Node.js just using nvm](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm) instead.

1. Clear NPM's cache:

   ```
    sudo npm cache clean -f
   ```
2. Install [a little helper called 'n'](//github.com/visionmedia/n)

   ```
    sudo npm install -g n
   ```
3. Install latest stable Node.js version

   ```
    sudo n stable
   ```

Alternatively pick a specific version and install like this:

```
sudo n 0.8.20
```

For production environments you might want to pay attention to [version numbering](//nodejs.org/documentation/contributing/) and be picky about odd/even numbers.

*Credits*

- General procedure: [D.Walsh](//web.archive.org/web/20150604015623/http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)
- Stable/unstable versions: [P.Teixeira](//books.google.com/books?id=ZH6bpbcrlvYC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=node+version+numbering+stable+unstable&source=bl&ots=mNCtczltJc&sig=u6cy5IbSW2J8lb_ahM5nbmMqbSs&hl=de&sa=X&ei=LiySVfmZEoLwUvXfqagE&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=node%20version%20numbering%20stable%20unstable&f=false)

Comment: You should credit your source - your answer is quoted from David Walsh's blog: http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs.

It should also be noted that this method has major caveats, some rather destructive, as seen in the comments on the original blog post.

Comment: Unfortunately that din't worked for me.. was doing exact as described on a Linux machine - 'node -v' before and after showed 'v0.10.5'

Comment: One more step. Close and re-open terminal or if using ssh, exit and log back in to see new node-v

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on raspberry pi B+ most likely the utility does not support the ARM version

Comment: did not success when node installed at a customized path

Comment: clearing cache may not be necessary. @ShawnErquhart I found http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/ which seems an older article - also the answer above doesn't appear to be a straight copy unless David Walsh's blog was updated and I missed it.

Comment: why sudo everything?

Comment: @Rob Imig : Globally installed scripts usually go to places like `/usr/local/bin` that require special permissions for installation.

Further information: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3139 
A possible fix/workaround (if you really want to avoid using `sudo`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724259/npm-command-sudo-or-not

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Linux. I get `sudo: n: command not found` for the third step.

Comment: I already downvoted this before because it's not cross platform. However, aditionally, this also DOES NOT install latest nodejs. It installed v4 while v6.10.0 is the latest available for download.

Comment: Seems to work for me but just followed the link to David Walsh's Blog above and he explicitly says not to use it - be warned!

Comment: Thanks brianjlennon for the hint. I updated my answer from 2013  accordingly. Including credits/links. I hope that's okay.

Comment: you should mention that your answer is NOT cross-platform or change it accordingly. Specifically, it is NOT working for WIndows (7, for example), that was several times mentioned other users.
Whtn you change it, i will take off my downvote, and may be upvote, if i like it.

Comment: I know this is old but none of the other suggestions worked for me. Turned out, just clearing npm's cache worked

Comment: This is a good solution if you are using a Linux distribution with deprecated packages like CentOS... Otherwise using `apt upgrade` to update Node.js in Debian / Ubuntu should be fine.

Comment: You can also update to the current LTS or latest release by using `nvm install --lts` or `nvm install --latest-npm`. For those not wanting to type the version number every time.

Comment: In order to install nvm on Windows (Win10 here), [you need a POSIX compliant shell like "BashOnWindows"](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1283#issuecomment-258030997). I highly recommend just [downloading the Node installer](https://nodejs.org/en/) and running it again. This will update Node and npm.

Comment: worked like a charm on orangepi5 running armbian, had to do only one more trick because it didnt worked properly at the begin using with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63306927/3982722

Answer (score 662):

Any OS (including Windows, Mac & Linux)

**Updated October 2022**

---

Just go to the official [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) site ([nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org)), download and execute the installer program.

It will take care of everything and with a few clicks of 'Next' you'll get the latest Node.js version running on your machine. Since 2020 it's the recommended way to update NodeJS. It's the easiest and least frustrating solution.

[image: Download NodeJS for Windows, buttons]

[image: Download NodeJS for Win/Mac/Source Code buttons]

---

**Pro tips**

- NodeJS installation includes NPM (Node package manager).
- To check your NPM version use `npm version` or `node --version`.
- If you prefer CLI, to update NPM use `npm install -g npm` and then `npm install -g node`.

  - For more details, see the docs for [`install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install) command.
- Keep an eye on [NodeJS blog - Vulnerabilities](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/) so you don't miss important security releases. Keep your NodeJS up-to-date.
- Operating systems supported by Node.js:

  - Windows, Linux, MacOS, IBM AIX.
  - For [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) users, here's the official [Node.js image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).
  - For more information on installing Node.js on a variety of less-common operating systems, see [this page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) (there's even Node for Android!).
- Troubleshooting for Windows:

  > If anyone gets file error 2502/2503 like myself during install, run
  > the .msi via Administrator command prompt with command `msiexec /package [node msi]`

---

<sup>If my answer is helpful, don't forget to upvote it</sup>
<sup>(here is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13770464/1429387) by Anmol Saraf, upvote it too)</sup>

Comment: So simple and obvious.. I was looking for a shortcut, but this way seems the simplest. `node --version` to check that it worked.. i had to google that too -- don't check my node version very often.

Comment: For those wondering if node modules will survive after running the newer version msi - the answer is yes! It worked for me too!

Comment: This didnt work for me. I have an ancient install of 0.10.26. I have been trying to install 6.10.0 LTS, but it seems impossible I can download and install 6.10.0 as many times as I want, the windows 10 machine can only see 0.10.26.  In "add remove programs" I only see 6.10.0.

Comment: Why exactly would you hyperlink operating systems' wiki pages?

Comment: I logged to upvote this and say that it should be the accepted answer. Anyway would be nice to have a node -u with confirmation or negation. I was searching through node --help realizing very quickly that it doesn't exist. I was surprised. But anway. Download + Execute is not such a big deal.

Comment: I prefer the CLI :D and I am a windows user. `npm install -g npm stable` then `npm install -g node`

Comment: I did do this before I found this answer since it is not on the top, which it should.

Comment: As usual in windows a double click is all you need to take care of the update. Can confirm having upgraded multiple times successfully simply by downloading the latest version and installing it.

Comment: As of Aug 2020 on a Mac, downloading from the node.js website seems to be the best method because "it just works". There's too many different ways to do it by CLI (just look at these answers), each those seem to have subtle conditions or unspoken assumptions, too many gotchas, and too many changes over the years. I think if you have to ask how to do this, the only answer is to download/install from node.js. Anything else is asking for confusion.

Comment: If anyone gets file error 2502/2503 like myself during install, run the .msi via Administrator command prompt with command `msiexec /package [node msi]`.

Comment: I couldn't get the installer to work on Windows 10, installing the latest LTS version. It would always error out in PowerShell when installing the additional requirements.

Comment: @BadHorsie did you try with elevated permissions (run PowerShell as Administrator)?

Comment: To check your NPM version use npm version or node --version.

If you prefer CLI, to update NPM use npm install -g npm and then npm install -g node.

work perfectly

Comment: Worth noting that in some cases this method will require a full system reboot to the latest version fully recognized and up and running. Particularly Windows 11 seems prone to this in for one reason or another recent testing.

Comment: This is simple and quick solution, this still works on node 17 and up, thank you naXa

Comment: This is the Obvious one and the best solution :)

Answer (score 465):

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed (only for macOS):

```
$ brew upgrade node
```

Comment: Agreed, I just run "brew upgrade" every few days and I'm kept up to date with the latest changes for all of my packages

Comment: This is a pain because it means having to upgrade xcode which means having to upgrade osx...

Comment: Mine says node not installed. Note: I didn't install node with homebrew. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: How to install specific version of node using brew ?

Comment: Never mind, found it at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171530/how-do-i-downgrade-node-or-install-a-specific-previous-version-using-homebrew

Comment: I wrote this super early in my career, and since then have had a chance to try a bunch of different techniques. I highly recommend installing `n` and using that if you can, à la another answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/392113

Comment: brew did some upgrade but still see the old node -v in the command line

Comment: while using npx create-react-app . i had node version incompatibility and did upgrade to latest version of node with brew upgrade node. Successfully upgraded to v15.0.1 however i did also faced error with yarn saying No such file or directory -/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4

Answer (score 403):

**2024: Just go to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) and use the latest installer.**

That's it folks. It used to be more complex and people used different kinds of packages and strategies to manage it. But things have changed for the better.

Works for all platforms (Windows, Mac & Linux).

Comment: After Setup re-installation gulp didn't work.
Then I called `npm rebuild` and it was fine again.

Comment: This didnt work for me. I have an ancient install of 0.10.26. I have been trying to install 6.10.0 LTS, but it seems impossible I can download and install 6.10.0 as many times as I want, the windows 10 machine can only see 0.10.26. In "add remove programs" I only see 6.10.0.  I cant find how to remove or update this old version, or how to install the new version over it. Any ideas?

Comment: For the last comment, you can use "where" command to find the executable. For example: 
"where node.exe". In my system (win10) this gives "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"

Comment: i concur, just go to nodejs.org and download and it will update everything automatically

Comment: I tried the other solutions to this question and this one was the easiest and least frustrating.

Comment: I had to run this after I had downloaded the new node.js from the website: `npm install -g node`

Comment: FYI I could not get this (NPM install) working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.  It would fail every time even when I chown the directories (as explained elsewhere). I also completely uninstalled my node installation, but it still wouldn't work. Finally, the only thing that I could do to get it to work was to install it via Snap.  Otherwise I could only get v8.10. Snap installed v12.18.3

Comment: Just in case, this doesn't work for Windows 7.

Answer (score 209):

First update `npm`,

**`npm install -g npm stable`**

Then update `node`,

**`npm install -g node`** or **`npm install -g n`**

check after version installation,

**`node --version`** or **`node -v`**

Comment: Be aware it worked for me under Windows 2016 but node was installed into the directory of the current user: `C:\Users\my-current-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\...`; it did not update an older installation under `C:\Program Files\nodejs` nor the path variable. i ended up reinstalling with the msi-installer. that fixed it for me.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Why? Later versions of npm require later version of node. Therefore you can update npm and then it stops working as you need a newer version of node. Thus you are back to the start and now your npm is broken.

Comment: its installs `6.8.0` for `npm` ,but i wants `6.11` for NodeJS, is it fine  to use `npm install -g npm`

Comment: After this we need to change symlink
`ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.17.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node`

Comment: As with @surfmuggle the above method wrongly installed node into `C:\Users\my-current-user\AppData\Roaming\npm`. To fix: I deleted that directory (`npm`) and removed it from my Windows Path. Then the command `node -v` would work to pickup the right node version installed from https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

Comment: This gave me the following warning `Node.js version v19.6.1 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.` And `npm install` just freezes

Answer (score 153):

On **Windows** you can use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to install and update Node.js (and lots of other packages).

**Install Node**

```
cinst nodejs.install
```

**Update Node**

```
cup nodejs.install
```

Note: You will need to install Chocolatey before you can use `cinst` and `cup`.

Comment: I was getting: _The schema version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc' is incompatible with version 2.1.31022.9038 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942._ When I tried to run the **cup nodejs.install**.  Found that if I run **nuget.exe update -self** on the nuget.exe in the C:\Chocolatey\chocolateyinstall directory.  Hope this helps anyone out there.

Comment: `cinst nodejs.install`
Chocolatey (v0.9.8.27) is installing 'nodejs.install' and dependencies. By installing you accept the license for 'nodejs.install' and each dependency you are installing.
Unable to find package 'nodejs.install'.

Command 'install' failed (sometimes this indicates a partial failure). Additional info/packages: nodejs.install

Comment: I feel a question about how you update Chocolatey coming on.

Comment: What's the difference between `nodejs.install` and `nodejs`?

Comment: @OhadSchneider if you use `.install` then you will be able to uninstall node from "Apps & features" in windows

Comment: On windows I recommend using winget [microsoft winget page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/). For me it's the smoothest experience I had with managing apps on windows. To upgrade node type `winget upgrade Node.js`

Answer (score 109):

To upgrade node to the latest version or to a specific version you can do the following:

```
sudo npm install n -g
sudo n 0.10.18   // This will give you the specific version
```

For the latest stable version:

```
sudo n stable
```

For the latest **LTS** version(Tested on Mac)

```
sudo n lts
```

Comment: Could you not do this in 2011? Why did everybody else answer with external solutions? +1 for using NPM and deserves answer IMO.

Comment: Worked for me on an AWS EC2 Linux instance

Comment: If you are trying to install "n" on windows, do not waste your time. At this time, still, "n" does not run on windows. For windows you either have to update from the installers on nodejs.org, use npm `npm install -g node``, use chocolaty, or install nvm (a third party version manager for node).

Comment: @ErikReppen n is a node package. This counts as "external" for me.

Answer (score 93):

To control your version of Node.js, you can try [*n*](https://github.com/visionmedia/n). I found it very straightforward and useful.

> n is a Node.js binary management, no subshells, no profile setup, no convoluted API, just simple.

```
npm install -g n
```

`n 0.6.19` will install Node.js v0.6.19.

Comment: Also you can switch between different nodejs versions, just type "n" and select version you need

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on Windows either.  The author should publish that fact.  It was a dead end for me.

Comment: It works for me in Windows within the git bash shell. So if you use git fire up git bash and try it there!

Comment: Doesn't work on Win7 for me - even in git bash. `npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: n@1.2.9
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32`

Comment: @backdesk on windows the upgrade process is almost the same as this install process. Full instructions here: http://exponential.io/blog/install-or-upgrade-nodejs-on-windows/

Comment: Git bash **does not** work for me on Windows 7, 64 bit OS.

Comment: Git bash **does not** work for me on Windows 10, 64 bit OS

Comment: Ugh!  Running this on an ARM processor, it says it's fetching a file that has the text "x86" in the title... and then promptly dies saying it cannot execute binary file (well duh!)

Comment: This does not work on linux either, it downloads the correct version but doesn't install it: http://pastebin.com/u708hRp9

Comment: This is the best way to go if `n` will run on your machine.

Comment: This doesn't work on my current version on node 17, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 63):

Short answer:

Go to this page: [Download | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Download the installer for your platform, then install it.

Comment: can you run it on ubuntu/LINUX ??

Comment: Not only for Windows, also on Mac this is the quickest

Comment: The OP have not mentioned anything about the platform, so the MSI answer is valid.

Comment: I revised the answer to say "Download the installer for your platform" instead. You're welcome :) @AshishRatan there are Linux binaries on the same page.

Comment: @ADTC `nvm` is the best solution

Comment: Now working for me on Ubuntu

Comment: @FabioDev Which command did you run to install it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem, when I saw that my Node.js installation is outdated.

These few lines will handle everything (for **[Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)**):

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

After this `node -v` will return you the latest available version.

Comment: Worked flawlessly on Mac OS X Yosemite too.

Comment: after doing this `node -v` still returned an older version number. But using `whereis node` I could actually detect that a recent version was installed in `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Worked without any hassle on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @bvbd the version of `node` that is used (by default) in this case likely depends on the order of directories in your `PATH`

Answer (score 23):

On CentOS 7 you can do the following:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.4.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
node –v (Should show updated version now)
npm rebuild node-sass (Optional: if you use this)
```

*Note: The symlink is required to link your node binary with the latest Node.js installed binary file.*

Comment: worked for me, important thing that I missed before was a symbolic linking.

Comment: Note that EPEL7 as of now has the latest long term stable version, so these steps are only recommended if you want something newer.

Comment: node –v
module.js:473
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/test/–v'

Comment: n latest 
/usr/bin/n: line 263: which: command not found
/usr/bin/n: line 263: which: command not found

Comment: @AlexeySh. It worked for me and apparently at least 16 other people.

Comment: For windows:-The NPM team officially recommends this method of updating Node. (source below)
 https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-update-npm-on-windows-10/
1.First, open PowerShell as administrator and run the following command.

>Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
>npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
>npm-windows-upgrade

Answer (score 14):

For OS X, I had v5.4.1 and needed the latest version 6 so I went to the [Node.js homepage](https://nodejs.org/en/) and clicked on one of the links below:

[image: Node.js OS X download links]

I then followed the installer and then I magically had the latest version of Node.js and npm.

Answer (score 9):

You may use nvm.

1. Check what is the latest version at http://nodejs.org/ (e.g. v0.10.26)
2. Run `nvm install v0.10.26`

Done.

You can choose which version to run:

`nvm ls` list the available versions and tells you which version you are using now.

`nvm use VERSION` change the current node to the requested version.

`nvm alias default VERSION` set the default version. The next time you source nvm.sh, this will be the version loaded (note that it doesn't change the version in use right now, run `nvm use` for that).

Comment: `nvm` is third party library :P

Comment: This is embarrassing. I used it since day one and didn't notice. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: `nvm alias default VERSION` was my savior!

Comment: I would also add `nvm copy-packages <previous version> ` to update all global dependencies at the end

Answer (score 9):

**For macOS in 2018+**
(as ALL of the solutions above are failing for me):

Simply go to the [official nodejs site](https://nodejs.org), download the official nodejs package and install it by double clicking. It's the most simple, safe and always-working thing you can do.

Answer (score 8):

Some Linux distributions such as [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) have Node.js in their package repositories. On such systems it is better to use a standard package update procedure, such as `pacman -Suy` or analogous `apt-get` or `yum` commands.

As of now (Nov 2016) EPEL7 offers a pretty recent version of Node.js (6.9.1 which is an up-to-date LTS version offered on the Node.js home page). So on CentOS 7 and derivatives you can just add EPEL repository by `yum install epel-release` and `yum install nodejs`.

CentOS 6/EPEL6 has 0.10.x which isn't supported upstream since Oct 2016.

Answer (score 7):

Today I ran on a Windows Git Bash:

```
$ npm i node -g
```

and got the following output:

```bsh
> node@10.6.0 preinstall C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

+ node-win-x64@10.6.0
added 1 package and audited 1 package in 23.368s
found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node -> C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node\bin\node
+ node@10.6.0
added 2 packages from 1 contributor in 26.089s
```

Read more about it at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node.

Comment: Same here. Out of nowhere my nodejs is deinstalled

Answer (score 6):

The easy way to update node and npm :

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

download the latest version of node js and update /install

Comment: you can drop the `@latest` part, it's the default behavior for npm.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ npm install -g npm stable
```

worked for me to update npm

Comment: This is to update npm and the question is for updating nodejs

Answer (score 5):

- Install nvm(cURL)

  $ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash

  OR with Wget

  $ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
- Display list of installed versions

  $ nvm ls
- Display list of versions that are available to install

  $ nvm ls-remote
- Install your preferred version

  $ nvm install v7.5.0
- Set this version as the default

  $ nvm alias default v7.5.0

Comment: NB: This will copy nvm.sh to your home directory. You should then run `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to set up the nvm command. Now you you can run `nvm ls`, etc as listed above. This is only necessary if you do not want to have to re-open your terminal, e.g. if you are SSH'd into a remote server.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

Comment: `curl {anything} | sudo bash -` can't possibly be a good security practice... Even leaving sophisticated attacks aside, what if you misspell the domain name?

Comment: Your comment adds no value to the answer. You can also misspell your bank domain and leak your bank details in a fake bank website.

Comment: Do not do `npm i n -g` afterwards to update node, because then you get two nodes on your system. Stay with this update process of `apt`. Alternatively you can try `snap` which also has a built-in update function

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) on Windows. It's very easy to use and useful for keeping you updated with other applications too.

Also, you can just simply download the latest version from https://nodejs.org and install it.

Comment: He asked "I did the following to update my npm: "npm update npm -g" But I have no idea how to update node.js. Any suggestions? (I'm using node.js 0.4.1 and want to update to node.js 0.6.1)." and I suggested him to use Chocolatey to simplify the process but I also suggested him to download the latest version from the site and install it, wich is more than enough to update the nodeJS as he asked. So, I think my answer does provide a satisfactory solution for his question.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#windows) Official Page, you can install&update new node version on windows using *[Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/)* or *[Scoop](http://scoop.sh/)*

**Using(Chocolatey):**

```
cinst nodejs
# or for full install with npm
cinst nodejs.install
```

**Using(Scoop):**

```
scoop install nodejs
```

Also you can download the [Windows Installer](http://nodejs.org/#download) directly from the nodejs.org web site

Answer (score 3):

As some of you already said, the easiest way is to update Node.js through the Node.js package manager, [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)). If you are a Linux ([Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)-based in my case) user I would suggest to add these lines to your `.bashrc` file (in home directory):

```
function nodejsupdate() {
    ARGC=$#
    version=latest
    if [ $ARGC != 0 ]; then
        version=$1
    fi
    sudo npm cache clean -f
    sudo npm install -g n
    sudo n $version
}
```

Restart your terminal after saving and write `nodejsupdate` to update to the latest version of Node.js or `nodejsupdate v6.0.0` (for example) to update to a specific version of Node.js.

BONUS: Update npm (add these lines to `.bashrc`)

```
function npmupdate() {
    sudo npm i npm -g
}
```

After restarting the terminal write `npmupdate` to update your node package manager to the latest version.

Now you can update Node.js and npm through your terminal (easier).

Answer (score 3):

In windows download the node executable file from the website and install it. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to version update of Node.js:

```
$ brew install node
```

If you don't have [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29); please go http://brew.sh/.

Comment: Homebrew doesn't work on all platforms that Node.js does.

Comment: Homebrew won't update a version of Node.js installed through some other means either. It will install parallel to it.

Comment: brew upgrade node

Answer (score 0):

Just install the new version over the current folder. I upgraded mine from v4.x to v6.10 on Windows.

Answer (score -3):

1. `npm clean cache` - you forget to clean ur cache
2. `npm update -g`

   This works on mine Windows, I hope it will also work for you :D

Comment: `npm cache clean` (a different order)

Comment: `npm update -g` command updates all globally installed packages, but not node.js itself.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to update Node.js, just try

```
npm update
```

from your Windows cmd prompt.

Else if you want to update any specific package try

```
npm update <package_name>
```

Example:

```
npm update phonegap
```

Comment: That's a great answer for a different question.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Before doing nmp update, node --version says 0.10.26. After doing update, same version. Even though the latest version is 7.7.1 or similar.

Comment: This didn't work for me either.

Answer (score -10):

open cmd and type

```
npm i -g npm
```