# node js fs module says object does not have method appendFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, fs

I'm building a node js app(for learning) where i'm logging each operation into a file called log.txt

The logger module has the following code :

```
var fs = require('fs');

function write(data,filename)
{
  var entry = 'Time: '+new Date();
  if(filename !=null || filename != undefined) entry = entry+'\n\tFile: '+filename;
  if(data !=null || data != undefined) entry = entry+'\n\tMessage: '+data;
  entry = entry+'\n';

  fs.appendFile('./log.txt',entry,function(err){
      if(err){console.log('Log NOT Appended with data:\n\t'+entry);}
      else{console.log('Log Appended with data:\n\t'+entry);}
  });
}

exports.write = write;
```

now in my app.js i'm requiring it as :

```
var logger = require('./logger');

var fs = require('fs');

function ReadFile()
{

  var data = fs.readFileSync('./config.txt');
  if(data==null) 
          logger.write("Config data not found");
  else
      logger.write(data,"app.js");
}

ReadFile();
```

This throws me back an error saying :

```
 Object #<Object> has no method 'appendFile'
```

However this worked fine earlier on a different pc, I noticed this when tried to run my
app on my system.

Comment: Can you share the version of node you're using on the failing pc?  appendFile is a newer method available as of v0.8

Comment: @michaelt I'm using v0.6.12, that might be the problem, i'll try updating and see if it works, thank you

Comment: yep that solved it, updated to v0.10.0 and now it works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the version, i was using v0.6.12 which did not have that method, i upgraded to v0.10.0 which solved it, thanks to michaelt for pointing it out.

Comment: n00b question, but how do you upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @jtromans you can use nvm(node version manager) or simply another module called "n" to upgrade and maintain versions of node on your system, for more details see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js-npm-and-all-other-dependencies