# npm command - sudo or not?

Tags: macos, npm, sudo

Currently I always run `sudo npm install <package-name>` but as I understand it's not correct.

I want to have opportunity not to use it as root/Administrator.
I followed some advice and used this command `sudo chown -R <username> ~/.npm` but it won't work...

for example, it's an output of my `npm install jade`

```
...
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine/-/amdefine-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine/-/amdefine-0.0.5.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../jade/bin/jade'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '../jade/bin/jade'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '../jade/bin/jade' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

as you see download started successfully but then failed..

I'm wondering what is the best way to disallow sudo on npm?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's possible (and advisable) to `npm install -g` node modules without `sudo`.

Check the permission of your `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` folder. I had installed node and npm through brew (without `sudo`) and that particular folder ended up being owned by root.

This fixed it for once and for all:

```
$ sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

(As for disallowing `sudo` with npm: you'd have to tweak npm for that. Your own node code could make use of https://npmjs.org/package/sudo-block, `npm install sudo-block`)

**EDIT:** even though this works, I no longer use `-g`. Instead use prefix (see next answer), or better yet use NIX https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381797 (even on OSX)

Comment: I had to change permissions for both 

    /usr/local/bin

and

    /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: @TelmoDias I had to the same too, it seems npm may have changed the directory it uses to install global packages

Comment: This is a bad general answer as this creates security issues with user(s) being able to modify binaries in global PATH. The second answer is better.

Comment: @PureW I don't disagree. I more and more leave packages local to the user or project folder. Nevertheless, the suggestion is still better than using `sudo`.

Comment: What if you had it already installed?  How do you find if it was installed with sudo vs not being installed with sudo?

Comment: -1 to answer, see [LFH](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html):

/usr is shareable, read-only data. That means that /usr should
be shareable between various FHS-compliant hosts and must not be written to.
Any information that is host-specific or varies with time is stored elsewhere.

Large software packages must not use a direct subdirectory under the /usr
hierarchy.

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion is the cleanest way to specify the npm prefix:

```
npm config set prefix ~/.node_modules
```

And then to add the following to you .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$PATH
```

Now the packages will install into your user directory and no permissions will be harmend.

---

EDIT: If you can't install **yeoman**, create a bash file in one of your PATH directories named **yodoctor** with the following contents

```
#!/bin/bash
yo doctor
```

Make the file executable with

```
chmod +x yodoctor
```

And now you should be able to install yeoman.

Comment: See npm's recommended options to fix npm permission problem: [https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions). This answer (from @febLey) is aligned with NPM's recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

and recursively change the files to your current user.

Comment: -1 to answer, see [LFH](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html):

/usr is shareable, read-only data. That means that /usr should
be shareable between various FHS-compliant hosts and must not be written to.
Any information that is host-specific or varies with time is stored elsewhere.

Large software packages must not use a direct subdirectory under the /usr
hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to be a better solution

`sudo chown -R $USER /Users/$USER`

This will just change the owner of your user to you and npm should be installed under your user on OS X.
Everything that I have been reading says sudo for npm installs is bad and I would have to agree with them as you open yourself up to malicious scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions offered here are are not something I would recommend because they are brute force solutions. Instead, I recommend reading [One does not simply sudo npm](https://coderwall.com/p/dxmfpg)