# Skip local installation of Gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Can I somehow skip local installation of Gulp to the project?

I installed Gulp globally, added it to package.json as a dependency. But still Gulp wants to be installed locally also with the `Local gulp not found in ...` message. If I do local install, Gulp is copied into my project by node.

Is there a way to skip local installation of Gulp? I want to be able to run it across the whole server from command line and manage it installation globally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One clean way to do this is without have it locally is to install **gulp** globally like as you did and then run in your directory the command :

```
npm link gulp
```

It will create a symbolic link in your `node_modules` folder to your global **gulp** install. You need to be careful on the versions since all your symlinks and therefore your local project(s) will use the global one, no matter of the defined version in the `package.json`, which could cause errors on a deployed environment.

This is also applicable for every node package, and allow you to update the local install you've created that way of multiple projects at once.