# How to use globally installed gulp modules?

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install, gulp-less

I tried [this tutorial](https://jeffshamley.com/blogs/compiling-less-files-gulpjs) to basically setup my gulp project and activate less processing and watching. It works. Now I'd like to install the modules globally, in order to acces them from everywhery on the machine and not to installa them for every project:

```
npm install --global gulp-less
npm install --global gulp-watch
npm install --global gulp-autoprefixer
npm install --global gulp-plumber
```

Now I want to run gulp in my project folder, but gulp cannot find the globally installed modules:

```
$ cd /my/project
$ gulp
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/temp/gulptest/gulpfile.js:9:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

How to get it working and use global gulp modules?

Comment: It's a bad practice to install modules globally.

Comment: I don't think so. At least in my case -- a local dev VM with similar projects -- it's a proper solution. Anyway -- this option is given, so I want to get it working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was [`npm-link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link). I had to link all my local packages to global counterparts:

```
npm link gulp
npm link gulp-less
npm link gulp-watch
npm link gulp-autoprefixer
npm link gulp-plumber
npm link path
```

Now it works.

Some StackOverflow posts to this subject:

- "[Skip local installation of Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363345/skip-local-installation-of-gulp)"

  - [Aperçu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054072/aper%c3%a7u)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25879563/2019043)
- "[Why do we need to install gulp globally and locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115400/why-do-we-need-to-install-gulp-globally-and-locally)"

  - [Derek Greer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219618/derek-greer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742196/2019043)

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Install gulp globally:

**If you have previously installed a version of gulp globally, please run `npm rm --global gulp`
to make sure your old version doesn't collide with gulp-cli.**

`$ npm install --global gulp-cli`

## 2. Install gulp in your project devDependencies:

`$ npm install --save-dev gulp`

Read more... https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: Global installs only worked for me with `sudo ....`, also if you need plugins/modules globally installed but locally used: `sudo npm install --global your-module` and then in the local path `sudo npm link your-module`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I solved this by placing this line at the top of my gulpfile.js

```
module.paths = module.paths.concat(module.parent.paths);
```

My parent module knew my npm global directory, but while running gulpfile.js, a child module seems to be created which doesn't. Instead, module paths is only relevant to the current directory from where the project is being run from and then each previous directory back to the root of my drive.