# ReferenceError: gulp is not defined

Tags: ubuntu, gulp

I planded backup/mirror all files inside my linux home directory.

my first, the default gulfile task will run and do nothing without errors:

i read here:

- [Skip local installation of Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363345/skip-local-installation-of-gulp)

i installed all in and from my home dir:

```
sudo apt install npm
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
npm link gulp
npm init
$ gulp
[07:32:43] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[07:32:43] Starting 'default'...
[07:32:43] Finished 'default' after 1.24 ms
```

i read here:

- [simple-gulp-copy-file-task](https://coderwall.com/p/9uzttg/simple-gulp-copy-file-task)

so i produced my first prototype  gulpfile.js :

```
function defaultTask(cb) {
    // place code for your default task here
    // cb();
    gulp.src('./gulpfile.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/media/me/sdd2 ntfs/backup/home/'));

        // .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
  }
  
  exports.default = defaultTask
```

now i get an error from my first prototype:

**ReferenceError: gulp is not defined**

```
$ gulp
[07:49:05] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[07:49:05] Starting 'default'...
[07:49:05] 'default' errored after 1.41 ms
[07:49:05] ReferenceError: gulp is not defined
    at defaultTask (/home/me/gulpfile.js:4:5)
    at taskWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:415:12)
    at asyncRunner (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

What can i do?

Comment: Did you do `const gulp = require('gulp')`  at the top of your gulpfile.js?

Comment: no becouse this line was not in the example. **the error is away.**