# TypeError: gulp.run is not a function

Tags: ubuntu, gulp

I planed backup/mirror all files inside my linux home directory.

first i read here: [Skip local installation of Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363345/skip-local-installation-of-gulp)

i installed all in and from my Linux home directory:

```
sudo apt install npm
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
npm link gulp
npm init
$ gulp
[07:32:43] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
[07:32:43] Starting 'default'...
[07:32:43] Finished 'default' after 1.24 ms
```

it starts, is waiting, and sends every time an error if a change happens:

**TypeError: gulp.run is not a function**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('backupHomeDir', function () {
    return gulp.src('./*.js') // read all of the files that are in js with a .js extension
      // .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js')); // write to the dist/js file
      .pipe(gulp.dest('/media/m/sdd2 ntfs/backup/home/'));
});
gulp.task('default', function () {
  // watch for changes
  gulp.watch('./*.js', function () {
      gulp.run('backupHomeDir');
    });
  });
```

I could start it by

```
$ sudo gulp
```

or

```
$ gulp
```

error is the same:

````
[12:32:19] Using gulpfile /home/m/gulpfile.js
[12:32:19] Starting 'default'...
[12:33:09] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[12:33:09] '<anonymous>' errored after 1.08 ms
[12:33:09] TypeError: gulp.run is not a function
    at /home/m/gulpfile.js:22:12
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:415:12)
    at asyncRunner (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remake `npm i` .
Second gulp.run is deprecated, you need just to use `gulp.watch()` and set an array of tasks as second params instead the callback, in your case here :

```
gulp.watch('./*.js', ['default','backupHomeDir']);
```

complete:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.js') // read all
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/media/m/sdd2 ntfs/backup/home/'));
});
gulp.watch('./*.js', gulp.series('default'));
```

Comment: works: 
```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*.js') // read all of the files that are in js with a .js extension
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/media/m/sdd2 ntfs/backup/home/'));
});
gulp.watch('./*.js', gulp.series('default'));