# Can I install just Gulp globally?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm constantly working on new web development projects that don't ever, in practice, need their `node_modules` folder when deploying. It would suit me much more if I was just able to create a small `gulpfile.js` for each project, rather than 6000+ files contained in the `node_modules` folder for every project, that are only ever used by me on this machine.

I only use Gulp to compile SASS and prefix and minify my CSS. I don't need to worry about any other type of deployment issues, but the documentation says I need both: Global and local copies of Gulp.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Gulp needs to be installed locally, but you can link the local install to a global install:

```
npm install --global gulp
npm link gulp
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742196/451480

Comment: Why would I want to link the local install to the global?

Comment: Linking prevents having 6000+ files in each project because you *link* to the global install, you don't *duplicate* the global install. You only have to do this for Gulp (see link for reason). Other NPM packages can be installed globally the normal way.

Comment: because working with docker, having `gulp` and gulp modules within the container to have everything compile safely (osx/win), linking it to a 'volume'  works nice with osx, but not with windows. Also requires (creates) a node_modules if non otherwise is needed.