# Gulp not installed globally?

Tags: gulp

I've installed Gulp like this:

npm install gulp -g

When I try `gulp -v` I get this:

```
[16:19:03] CLI version 3.9.1
```

But when I try to use gulp in my project by running gulp `enter code here` I receive:

```
[16:20:40] Local gulp not found in ~/Code/gulp
[16:20:40] Try running: npm install gulp
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need to install gulp globally and locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115400/why-do-we-need-to-install-gulp-globally-and-locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gulp requires two parts to work in any project:

1. the `gulp` object that has the 5 functions attached, (`src`,`dest`, `watch`, `run`, `task`). this is installed locally for a project, as well as all the plugins necessary, because it is included in your taskfiles such as `gulpfile.js`. Its a locally imported module.

`npm install --save-dev gulp`

2. the `gulp-cli`, because this is a command line utility, that can be called from anywhere on your computer. Its a globally accessible cli command. You console needs to be able to see it. You do not import this.

`npm install -g --save gulp-cli`

you can see more here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cli/tutorial

Comment: thanks for the answer. Fyi the link no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install gulp inside your project:

`npm install --save-dev gulp`