# Local gulp not found (Try running: npm install gulp)

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-install, post-install

I created a module (`webapp-module-storage`) which has the following definitions:

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    ...
  },
  "name": "webapp-module-storage",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "gulp build",
    "test": "gulp test"
  }
}
```

I thought I can use my module inside another module when installing it with:

- `npm install github:myorg/webapp-module-storage#master`

However, when I install my module, I am getting this error:

> Local gulp not found
>
> Try running: npm install gulp

**Screenshot**

[image]

My understanding is, that `gulp` is shipped together with my module because I declared it in `devDependencies` but it looks like that my `npm postinstall` script cannot find `gulp`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies)

Comment: Perform `npm i gulp -D` in folder project. Note: gulp4 can cause issues in old projects, for install a specific version use like this: `npm i gulp@3.9.1 -D` (ps `-D` for devDependencies)

Answer (score 199):

Try running `npm link gulp` in your application directory (to create a local link to the globally installed Gulp module).

Comment: Laravel / homestead user here. The above command didn't work for me, however `npm link gulp --no-bin-links` worked.

Comment: To clarify, `npm link [module]` creates a symlink from [module]'s global install folder to ./node_modules/[module] at the current path (`npm link` w/o name links packages, see [man page](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/d46015256941ddfff1463338e3e2f8f77624a1ff/doc/cli/npm-link.md))

Answer (score 25):

Try installing your dependencies first:

```
npm install
```

If still does not work, install gulp globally:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

if you find problems installing it. type **sudo** before **npm**.

In case you need more info about why you need gulp globally and locally read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115400/why-do-we-need-to-install-gulp-globally-and-locally) answer

Comment: Gulp is installed globally: `[17:51:24] CLI version 1.2.1`

Comment: Actually not in the application using my module. But I thought that it would grab `gulp` from the path of my module or my globally installed gulp.

Comment: Seems it is searching for the local gulp inside your project. How about install it locally, inside your project  ?

Answer (score 17):

I have tried all the solutions mentioned. At the end I was able to solve the problem by realising that the **gulpfile.js** file was missing on the location i was using the gulp. After placing the gulpfile.js in the folder from where I was executing gulp, it worked for me.

Comment: I made the same mistake. I was one directory up from where I was suppose to be.  This can easily happen if you are going full speed with setting up something like an Express Generator environment where you have multiple sub apps under a root location.  I just needed to slow down.

Answer (score 3):

`npm link gulp --no-bin-links`

Run this

where `npm link gulp` creates a local link to globally installed gulp module and `--no-bin-links` argument will prevent npm from creating symlinks for any binaries the package might contain.

You can't translate symlinks to a synchronized folder on Windows share, so you will need '--no-bin-links' to go around it.

Use it for any filesystem that doesn’t support symbolic links.

**Symlinks**, or symbolic links, are “virtual” files or folders which reference a physical file or folder located elsewhere, and are an important feature built in to many operating systems, including Linux and Windows.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you @Brain for pointing out :). I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

`npm link gulp --force`

Using this command worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I used Visual Studio Code and Terminal with Power Shell and have this problem either. This problem for me disappeared when I changed Execution Policy. I get info about this solution from [gulp](https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/solved-gulp-file-c-users-tech-appdata-roaming-npm-gulp-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system-with-code-examples/). Execution Policy changin example is in the picture.[image: Set Execution Policy]

Answer (score 0):

Put Gulp into the regular dependencies of the project:

```sh
npm i gulp
```

And then have your scripts section reference the local Gulp like that:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp build",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp test"
  }
```