# Gulp doesn't seem to work after installing globally

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2017

I installed gulp globally using this tutorial:
https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/

When I run "gulp -v" I get:

CLI version 3.9.1

Now I navigate to the root of our Visual Studio 2017 project where our "gulpfile.js" file is.
And I try to run >gulp watch.

It says:

```
C:\Development\DOD-SECO>gulp watch
[16:41:44] Local gulp not found in C:\Development\DOD-SECO
[16:41:44] Try running: npm install gulp
```

How do I get the global gulp install to run the watch script and watch for SASS to CSS compilations?

**UPDATE 1**

I got it to run.  But I had to CD to the Content dir where our SASS and CSS folders are even though the gulpfile.js file is on the root of the project.
Not sure why yet.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103889/local-gulp-not-found-try-running-npm-install-gulp

Comment: Install gulp locally as well.