# Docker Compose w/ Gulp - Local gulp not found

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, docker-compose

I am attempting to use gulp inside a Docker container.

I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:alpine
RUN apk --update add --no-cache git nodejs
RUN npm install --global gulp
ENV GOPATH=/go PATH=$PATH:/go/bin
VOLUME ["/go/src/github.com/me/sandbox", "/go/pkg","/go/bin"]
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/me/sandbox
CMD ["gulp"]
```

and I have the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
service:
    build: ./service
    volumes:
        - ./service/src/:/go/src/github.com/me/sandbox
```

`docker-compose build` builds successfully, but when I run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error message

```
Recreating sandbox_service_1
Attaching to sandbox_service_1
service_1  | [22:03:40] Local gulp not found in /go/src/github.com/me/sandbox
service_1  | [22:03:40] Try running: npm install gulp
```

I have tried several different things to try to fix it.

- Tried also installing `gulp-cli` globally and locally
- Tried installing `gulp` locally with `npm install gulp`
- Tried moving the `npm install --global gulp` after the `WORKDIR`
- Tried different paths for volumes.

My guess is that it has something to do with the volumes, because when I get rid of anything having to do with a volume, it doesn't complain.

Mr project structure is shown in screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need to install gulp globally and locally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115400/why-do-we-need-to-install-gulp-globally-and-locally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a local version of gulp as well as a global one.

Adding this line should fix your issue

```
RUN npm i gulp
```

Comment: Has a bug with install gulp inside docker, use gulp-cli instead. `npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: natives@https://registry.npmjs.org/natives/-/natives-1.1.4.tgz
`

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me.

```
RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm link gulp
```

Comment: This option worked for me! The other options listed in this post didn't work.