# Local gulp not found inside docker container

Tags: django, docker, gulp

I am trying to rebuild a past project regarding Django and gulp.js. Gulp is used to build the static assets from Django. I am now dockerizing this project. In order to do it, I am using a python and node combo image from this [hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs). I install the necessary packages both from Django and node. I copy the source code into the container. Run `gulp` and `./manage.py runserver`. When I run `gulp`, I get an error that the local gulp cannot be found in the directory.

```
app  | [06:49:46] Local gulp not found in /usr/src/app
app  | [06:49:46] Try running: yarn add gulp
```

I have this directory tree. The `src/` holds the source codes and I copy this to the container. It holds the `gulpfile.js` and `manage.py`.

```
.
└── project/
    ├── dockerfiles/
    │   └── app.Dockerfile
    ├── src/
    │   ├── apps/
    │   ├── entrypoints/
    │   │   └── entrypoint-local.sh
    │   ├── gulpfile.js
    │   ├── manage.py
    │   ├── package.json
    │   └── package-lock.json
    ├── .local.env
    └── docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.9"

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/app.Dockerfile
    entrypoint: ./entrypoints/entrypoint-local.sh
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .local.env
```

Here is how I build the `app` container.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.7-nodejs19-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev libgeos-dev gdal-bin libgeoip1 libgdal-dev gdal-bin \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv \
    && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY /src/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY /src/package*.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
RUN npm install --save-dev gulp

COPY /src .

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoints --recursive
```

In my entrypoint, I first run `gulp` before `./manage.py runserver`.

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate --no-input
gulp
python manage.py runserver
```

The gulp command triggers the error from the above. I have tried placing a list directory in the entrypoint to check if `gulpfile.js` is present and can confirm it is present. I also tried to remove the `gulp` command and run `./manage.py runserver` and the Django runs. Why am I getting that error and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028272/docker-compose-w-gulp-local-gulp-not-found ?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a directory `/usr/src/app` inside the container (`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`) where you install the Node.js requirements.

Then you overwrite that directory with a volume mapping:

```
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
```

This will *replace* the directory `/usr/src/app` inside the container (where you just installed all the requirements) with the contents of `./src`.

Comment: So should I remove it? How can I persist the source code?

Comment: The manage.py does not produce error though.

Comment: AFAIK, `pip` installs requirements in a global directory, not a local one, which is why `manage.py` is working. Since you're already copying files into the container (`COPY`), you don't need to use a volume mapping.

Comment: But I need to persist the `/src` directory to that in the container, since I am going to develop some new features. Should I just also persist the `node_modules` when install packages from node?

Comment: In that case you need to have all the required Node.js files outside of the container, including `node_modules` (you can then drop all the Node.js-related `COPY` commands).