# ionic installation in mac

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

Continuously getting an error. Please help me to setup ionic and Cordova for mac.

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@9.5.0 (node-v59 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v9.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v9.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Format your question and update for which command you are getting this error.  Try once using `sudo`.

Comment: Don't use sudo for npm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724259/npm-command-sudo-or-not

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: sudo npm install -g cordova ionic..... I am getting error for this command

Comment: check the link I commented.. you need to either configure npm to avoid sudo or use sudo

Comment: yes, I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: node-pre-gyp ERR! <== i am getting this type of error not EACCES

Comment: `gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'`

Comment: please tell me about what to do exactly to solve the error?