# How to install vue cli without any errors from npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue-cli

I am trying to install Vue-CLI.

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

But i have lots of errors.

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! code EACCES
>   npm ERR! syscall access
>   npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] {
>   npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access'/usr/lib/node_modules'",
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR! }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>   npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access thisfile as the current user
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
>   npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
>   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

I tried to reinstall `nodejs` & `npm` and I also tried to updtate `code-js` to 3 version, but that didn't work out.

Comment: did you try running as `sudo` - looks like you don't have permissions to the `node_modules` folder. You can run it as `sudo` or give yourself permissions to said folder

Comment: **Do not run as sudo!** Fix where `npm` is trying to install global packages by following the instructions on npm's website: [Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).  Running as sudo will give you even more issues down the line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm command - sudo or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724259/npm-command-sudo-or-not)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run `npm install -g @vue/cli` as a `root` user.

> sudo npm install -g @vue/cli

Comment: The answer should be the @zero298 link. It worked for me, and it is the best to do.

Answer (score 1):

try `npm uninstall vue-cli`

then `npm install @vue/cli` this is to install vue and upgrade to Vue 3 cli