# gulp-inject not working in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net, gulp, asp.net-core, gulp-inject

So I've been working on a asp.net core project and trying to inject scripts using the gulp-inject package. but when I try to use the gulp-inject module in gulpfile.js it throws this error in task-runner window. what am I missing here?

[image: [gulp-inject in package.json]

gulp-inject in package.json

[image: task-runner error]

task-runner error

Comment: can you post the gulpfile? possibly as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/issues/171). You need to upgrade your version of **NodeJS to v4**.

To see your version, open a command prompt and run:

```
node --version
```

To upgrade, go to https://nodejs.org and find the downloads or look at [How do I update node and npm on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows)

If you're using Visual Studio 2015, also check the version of NodeJS that it is using. Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools shows the locations. From there either:

1. add C:\Program Files\nodejs as the new top entry, or
2. move the `$(PATH)` to the top if it is already up-to-date.

[image: External Web Tools]

Comment: my node version is 4.2.3. still having the issue

Comment: @FiyazBinHasan I added a way to investigate Visual Studio's tooling.

Comment: i've moved the $(PATH) to the top. since my path is updated now its working. but is it a preferred way?

Comment: @FiyazBinHasan Moving the `$(PATH)` to the top seems like a good way to me. Well done. I suppose you could also investigate where the other `NodeJS` installation is located and then update it too. That would be thorough though probably not necessary.