# npm install giving error

Tags: npm

I am trying to install should using the below command:

```
npm install --save-dev should
```

but getting below error everytime:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\gyanendra_nath\\
AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev
" "should"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gyanendra_nath\Node\Supertest\npm-debug.log
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I even tried changing `PATH` value under environment variables and also removing proxy using below commands:

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

npm config get proxy
>> got this as a response " http://domain/username:password@10.74.91.103:80"
```

Please help me out on how to fix the issue.

Comment: I am wondering whether the below solution resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below command. If there is no problem with proxy, this should work.

```
npm install -g should@10.0.0
```

This should install the package in the below path.

```
C:\Users\gyanendra_nath\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\should
```

I have used the below versions.

```
node --version
v6.1.0

npm --version
3.8.6
```

My Path variable is set to

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

If you would like to upgrade your node version, please refer the below link.

[Upgrade node and npm on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows)