# Updating NPM with Nodist

Tags: node.js, npm, nodist

I'm unable to update `npm`, and get it to use with [Nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist).

Whenever I try to update `npm` with the command

```
npm install -g npm
```

the following message comes right after executing it:

> (node:5304) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. 
>       If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\v\nodev6.5.0\npm -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\v\nodev6.5.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
>
> npm@3.10.6 C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\v\nodev6.5.0\node_modules\npm

Doing an `npm -v` right after, gives me the previous version:

```
...> npm -v
2.14.10
```

However, if you noticed the last line in the message above, there is `npm@3.10.6` which means it is somehow trying to install *that* version of `npm`.

I also followed instructions from [*this*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562417/how-do-you-update-npm-to-the-latest-version) post for Ubuntu users and [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows) for Windows users, but they seem to address issues with standalone `NodeJS` installations and *NOT* `NodeJS` + Nodist combo.

Meanwhile, I was wondering if Nodist itself enables us to update `npm`, or in other words, does it have any version management feature for `npm` as well, just as it does for `node`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

---

#### Additional Info

I am using Nodist `v0.7.1` on Windows 7.

Comment: https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist#commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Nodist versions prior to `v0.7.2` have an issue with getting `npm` set with Nodist correctly (refer the Nodist [changelog](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist#changelog)).

Performing an `npm install -g npm` was in fact installing the latest version of `npm` under the `v-x64` in Nodist's root installation folder - ***which is not where Nodist itself looks for `npm` installation***.

Nodist looks for `npm` inside the `\bin` folder:

[image]

### Solution

1. Add the `bin` folder's path to your PATH.
2. `cd` to the Nodist installation > `bin` directory with your terminal, 
   and then perform:

   ```
    npm install npm
   ```

   (*not with `-g` flag of course*).

   Alternatively, if `npm install` doesn't work in this step, copy an already installed `npm` and paste it in the `node_modules` folder within the `bin` directory.

---

As a side note, remember to remove some values from your PATH which I suppose may cause conflicts with global package installations (i.e. with `-g` flag) with `npm`, before installing Nodist, which are as follows:

- `%appdata%\npm;` OR `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;`
- `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs;`

Answer (score 5):

You can try `nodist npm latest`

Nodist manages npm versions as well as node versions.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same issue.

You should use the following command `nodist npm 6.14.5`, changing the version you need.

And you can see more option whith this command: `nodist --help` is where I found the answer:
[see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI94y.png)