# npm -v still showing version 2.x.x after installing npm3

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am starting to use Angular 2, which requires npm `3.x.x`, so I installed it with `npm install -g npm3`. The Angular 2 tutorials tell me to verify that I have npm `3.x.x` by running `npm -v`, however when I run that, it still says I have version `2.15.8`. It shows that I have version `3.10.7` if I run `npm3 -v`, but not if I run `npm -v`. Is this going to cause errors? Do I need to it to say I'm using version `3.x.x` when I run `npm -v`? If so, what do I need to do?

EDIT:
Node.js version: `node -v` reveals that I am using v4.4.7  (Angular2 requires something between `4.4.x` - `5.x.x`, so I should be good here)
OS: I am currently using Windows 10 on a PC, but have had the same issue with my Mac.

Comment: You did not specify OS and Node.js version ?

Comment: npm gets installed with node js, what is the version of node you are seeing? if you are using angular-cli you will run into issues with older version of npm.

Comment: I think it is related to this one [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6237400/1181036](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6237400/1181036)

Comment: @ArifKhan Updated question with Node.js version and OS

Comment: Upgrade npm using this command - `npm install -g npm`

Comment: @Sanket npm -v now says I am using v3.10.7. Thanks!

Comment: @Sanket has the best answer. How do I mark this as resolved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update node and npm on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows)

Comment: @Brett added as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade npm using this command - `npm install -g npm`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

https://www.google.de/search?q=update+npm+windows

Updating npm with npm itself will store `npm.cmd` in `../appdata/roaming/`.
To avoid conflicts with an older npm version you need to remove `npm.cmd` from  `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`