# 'ng serve' does not work after a double install

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I used to have Angular CLI, but I mistakenly installed it again with

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

And now when I run `ng serve` it complains:

> It seems like you're using a project generated using an old version of the Angular CLI.
>
> The latest CLI now uses webpack and includes a lot of improvements, include a simpler
> workflow, a faster build and smaller bundles.
>
> To get more info, including a step-by-step guide to upgrade the CLI, follow this link:
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.12

When I try to create a new project using `ng new` in another directory, it complains that:

> Cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'

So what is the problem?

Comment: Try `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` & `npm cache clear`. Then install the global CLI again.

Comment: doesn't work. I tried it

Comment: I had the same issue after updating git for windows. Reinstalling CLI package helped. Don't forget restart your console after changing system PATH variable.

Comment: Please make the local and global versions of the cli same.

Comment: I have all the required sw installed and can verify by checking their versions, but `ng serve` still does not work and only shows a new prompt again. What do I do? This happened out of the blue, on a project that I have been working on for a while now...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key is to have both *global* and *local* Angular-cli versions the same.

Let's say we want to fixate it to eg. `1.0.0-beta.15`.

So you can try to fixate the version in `npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.15` and in your `package.json` fixate it to the same version: `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15"`. Then run `npm install --save-dev`.

Currently Angular CLI can be found on NPM under `@angular/cli` instead of `angular-cli`. Here are links to documentation how to [uninstall old](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update#1-uninstall-old-version) and [install the latest](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update#3-install-the-new-version) version of CLI.

Comment: Well, you have to have both - one inside your project's `node_modules` and the other globally in your *Node.js* `node_modules`. The CLI works this way.

Comment: You can fixate your Angular framework version in your `package.json` to the RC5 by removing the `^` chars in front of the version string - if you want to.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are probably using an old version of Angular CLI. You can reinstall the latest version by the following command.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Comment: Becareful, this is a global modification, may be you just want to fix 1 project.

Answer (score 10):

Try commands

```
npm start ng s
```

or

```
npm start
```

Comment: Check you are not serving a blank page :-)

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot. When I ran 'npm start', it showed that I was getting an "Access is denied" error when trying to run the ng command. Turns out my company was blocking the ng.exe.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is it supposed to accomplish? Why is it necessary? What is the idea/gist? Under what circumstances should it be used? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51422389/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: I should add if you get errors when doing npm, its bc of dependencies or version differences, so you should do `npm start --force`

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing this, but now it’s resolved:

Put this line in file *package.json* for *start*:

```
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201"
```

Answer (score 5):

On [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), firstly do:

```
npm install --save-dev
```

Try:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and then try:

```
ng serve
```

This will work 100%.

Comment: global installation with "sudo" is not recommended, no

Comment: What version of Ubuntu was it tested on? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55357961/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

I used `ng serve --open`, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. This works for me.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install --cache/tmp/empty-cache
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
cd "yourProjectName"
ng serve -o
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Does it differ from some standard procedure? Why does it differ? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55358185/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I was using a higher version of Angular (8+) which was not compatible with Node.js version v8.11.3. I was even getting exit status code 3. So I installed it using the Windows [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer and it upgraded my version of Node.js.

Courtesy - *[How can I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows/31520672#31520672)*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using a Linux machine and I solved it by using `sudo`

Just add `sudo` before your `ng serve` command. For example:

```
sudo ng serve --port 6161
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to your project and try this code:

```
npm i https://github.com/Qix-/node-error-ex <br/>
npm install <br/>
ng serve --open
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), follow the following steps:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev

sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

ng serve
```

This will definitely work.

Comment: It didn't work, the app does not start the serve, just shows the prompt again

Comment: @3xCh1_23 I have the same problem; the app does not serve but just shows the prompt again. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

1. Open with **Live Server**       (If Working on Index.html or app.component.html)
2. Type  ***ng serve --open***     (In VS Code Terminal)

Changes will be visible on  http://localhost:4200/

If you are using VS Code then open whole folder in VS Code.

Code runner won't work - "Code language not supported or defined"

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First run command

```
npm i
```

That will download the dependencies. Once done, run

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if you face that kind of problem:

1. delete `node_modules` folder
2. run: `npm install`
3. run: `ng serve`

watch for the missing module error report.
For example: if the error says something like `'abcd.module' is missing`, then find your angular project version with:

1. go to your project directory
2. run : `ng --version`
   you'll see a lot of modules, pay attention to the version. If the majority
   is like version **12.2.13** (for example), then:
3. run: `npm install @angular/abcd@12.2.13`
   The version number is very important.

Then run: `ng serve`

This always works for me, in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest

Also check system environment variables
path  =>

1. C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin
2. C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular
3. C:\Users\a\AppData\Roaming\npm

This fixed my issue

Answer (score -1):

I tried literally everything, but this one worked for me:

Go to:

```
C:\Users\<profile_name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
```

**Don't forget** ***ng*** **at the end**

Then try:

`ng -v` (to show the version of `ng`)

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Comment: Why is getting it to ***display the version information*** accomplishing anything? Are there some (positive) side effects to the state of the system by doing this? Isn't there more to this story? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54069252/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This does nothing but output your current ng version to the console. Downvoted.