# Angular Cli show's no ouput when using "ng s -o/ng s/ng build"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when using "ng serve", "ng serve -o" and "ng build" the show's no output.
if anyone can help, pls help me I need angular for my project.
[image]

Comment: Have you installed @angular/cli globally?

Comment: yes, until yesterday it was working, but when I want to run it today, it doesn't show anything @Celsiuss

Answer (score 0):

For more information, you could show the content of the node_modules folder or tell us if it is empty, and what appears when using these commands in the console:

```
ng version

node -v

npm -v
```

Comment: Hi friend, ng version ( Angular CLI: 12.0.5
Node: 14.17.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13) @Jesús Giménez

Comment: I have restarted my PC, removed Node_modules folder and reinstalled it but no result, same to same, can u help me?

Comment: Can you add the full package.json code to try to reproduce it? This answer may help you fix it: [Global and local Angular-cli versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774999/13091702)

Comment: Thanks, Friend, I have installed Angular-CLI v12, and the new project I have installed and works, thanks for your time. @Jesús Giménez