# ng serve has no ouput

Tags: npm, angular-cli, angular-devkit

I recently cloned a repo onto a new machine and now I have run into some issues in getting my development server up and running. When I run `ng serve`, there is no output in the terminal as seen below. [image: command line interface with blank output from ng serve]

This is strange to me because when I created a fresh angular project and ran the same command, the server builds successfully. I'm not sure what I'm missing here to allow my server to build and run.

I have taken the following steps so far:

- uninstalled @angular/cli globally and locally, and reconciled their versions to be the same as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774999/12936248
- installed angular-devkit/build-angular@0.80 to match the local version within my repo
- Matched angular.json in the original and the fresh project, as the fields for `development` within the `serve` object did not exist in the original project.

But none of these can bring output to this command. Could someone please point me in the right direction so I may be able to get through this issue? This is my package.json below, and you may view my project at https://github.com/andrervincent/nbd

````
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1300.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.25",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}```
````

Comment: try running it using npm     npm run start

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AwabilGeorge. I've also tried this and this lead to the same outcome, no output.

Comment: This is still a problem for me, I have uninstalled and reinstalled angular-cli, as well as aligned my versions of angular(13.0.4) and node(12.20.1) to be compatible. What else can I do to fix this? The problem is that the `ng serve` nor the `ng build` command has any output. The terminal simply hangs, then prompts me again.

Answer (score 1):

try doing "git clean -fdx" and then do a fresh installation of dependencies by running "npm install". Then simply run "npm run start", It will start the project.