# NPM package installation fails for @progress/kendo-angular-buttons

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to add New Component of KendoUI through Node package manager and unfortunately got below error:

**Reference URL :** http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/

[image]

Guide me to resolve above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Angular examples, as well as Kendo UI for Angular 2, [require NPM v3](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520672/25427) for more information on how to update NPM on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The steps are mentioned in the link that you provided

[http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/getting-started/)

To enable the Progress NPM registry on your machine, you should associate the @progress scope with the registry URL. Run the following command in your terminal:

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress
```

NPM will ask you for your Telerik account credentials and an email. Enter the username (if username is email address use everything before the @) and password you use to log in your Telerik account.

After that just simply run

```
npm install
```