# npm install of Kendo-UI-Angular 2 returns service unavailable

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I went to the kendo-UI site and registered for a free 30 day trial of kendo-ui for angular.  Following the instructions for the [getting started guide](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#toc-add-the-progress-npm-registry), I tried `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @angular/animations` but nothing got added to the node modules folder.
After some digging I came across [this post](https://www.angularattack.com/blog), which mentions that you have to enter your telerik credentials to access the private npm registry.  So I followed these instructions and ran `npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress`.
At this point I was prompted to login with username and login.  I read on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302633/4023777) that the username is everything before the "@" symbol of your Telerik/Progress login.
So I tried to login with this as my username, my Telerik/Progress email address and password.  Which gave me a service unavailable response...
[image: kendo ui service unavailable message]

All other research has turned up this same information.
My NPM version is 4.2.0.
I have looked on the kendo-ui documentation and haven't found anything.
So, How do I install kendo-ui for demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to dig I found [this](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/712) on the kendo angular github page.
According to that disccussion this.. is wrong `npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress` since they moved the registry from npm to npmjs

I changed it to `npm login --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org  --scope=@progress`  Once I entered my  username (everything before the "@" symbol of your Telerik/Progress login), password and email address i received
 `Logged in as jay.culpepper to scope @progress on https://registry.npmjs.org/.`.
Then when I ran `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons @progress/kendo-angular-l10` it worked.

Comment: The whole discussion can be found here - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/712

Answer (score 0):

Remove lines below from your %USERPROFILE%\.npmrc file.

```
@progress:registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
//registry.npm.telerik.com/:_authToken=<token>
```