# Angular CLI can't find modules

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install, package.json

I have copied a project in a new repository.

Then I tried to delete node_modules folder then tape :

```
npm install
```

to install missing dependencies

But after installation and when I run my project using angular-CLI it does not find modules and show this errors:

```
ERROR in /home/haddad/projects/portfolio/src/app/app.component.ts (1,62): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/haddad/projects/portfolio/src/app/app.component.ts (2,54): Cannot find module 'ngx-fullpage'.


ERROR in /home/haddad/projects/portfolio/src/app/menu-accueil/menu-accueil.component.ts (2,31): Cannot find module '@angular/material'.
```

Here's my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "siteperso",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "^0.9.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-fullpage": "^4.0.6",
    "particlesjs": "^2.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.2",
    "typeit": "^4.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.29",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

I have also uninstall angular-cli then reinstall it back but no result .

**UPDATE** , I have noticed that the missing modules are the locked directory @angular in node_modules folder.

even after using  `sudo chown -R ./node_modules/` I got the same error

Comment: Why did you use sudo?

Comment: I'm in Ubuntu, for administrator right

Comment: Why you need administrator rights when you just install dependencies? I use macOS and I never install deps using sudo....

Comment: I don't think that the problem is that.

Comment: I don't say that the problem is that. I am just wondering why you use sudo there.

Comment: When exactly cli says that about modules? Do this modules really exist in node_modules?

Comment: yes they exist. Other module are missing but I have not added them in my post. It shows that when I use ng serve.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `npm install` in the correct directory (i.e. `/home/haddad/projects/portfolio`)? Just wondering...

Comment: @infodev update the packages to latest version. delete node_modules folder and install the packages using npm install

Comment: did you try doing a `npm cache  clean`

Comment: Try what @RahulSingh said. And if that doesn;t work, try changing the permissions of the node_modules, instead of changing the owner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install fails on FAT32 sile system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691251/npm-install-fails-on-fat32-sile-system)