# Running or updating gulp with node or npm issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

Trying to troubleshoot an issue, but not sure why out of the blue, I cannot install `gulp` locally. This is in any folder on my machine.

Here is what I get:

```
C:\source\portalTest>npm install gulp

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: C:\app\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\cmd\git.EXE clone --depth=1 -q -b 1681/head git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-3782b653 --config core.longpaths=true
npm ERR! warning: templates not found C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pacote-git-template-tmp\git-clone-b45c0eb0
npm ERR! warning: Could not find remote branch 1681/head to clone.
npm ERR! fatal: Remote branch 1681/head not found in upstream origin
npm ERR!
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-02T19_24_16_382Z-debug.log
```

Anyone know why this happened out of the blue and how to fix this? Have tried `npm cache clean` and anything else I could find on the internet but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you using the **latest** node & npm ?(otherwise this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows/31520672#31520672)

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest

Comment: Actually from the *ERR message*, `C:\app\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\cmd\git.EXE clone --depth=1 -q -b 1681/head git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-3782b653 --config core.longpaths=true` fails as the `1681/head` branch doesn't exist on GitHub registry: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/branches

Comment: that happens no matter what I do. reinstall node, etc.... doesn't matter what shell I use either.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the shell, it's more like a NPM's issue, can you install other packages locally using NPM?