# How to upgrade from Node.js version v4.4.5 to v6.11.0 on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, node-modules

```
 npm cache clean
 npm update -g
```

I used the following instructions to upgrade but still it dint update. Any suggestions? (I'm using Node.js 4.4.5 and want to update to Node.js 6.11.0.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update node and npm on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows)

Comment: @KarelG I can see in that other question that there's a lot of effort around upgrading Node on Windows. Does the regular *.msi installer have known issues? Should I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Just run the set of commands to upgrade node and npm versions:
Run PowerShell as Administrator

- **Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force**
- **npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade**
- **npm-windows-upgrade**

To upgrade to specific node version, run the following command:

- **npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest**

To manually specify a version:

- **npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version xyz**

go through the official npm documentation: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade