# Visual Studio Code (Windows) Not Detecting Global NPM Modules

Tags: npm, environment-variables, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing an issue where Visual Studio Code in Windows 10 is not able to detect globally installed NPM packages within the Integrated Terminal.

For example, if the windows command prompt I install `@angular/cli` via command `npm install -g @angular/cli`, within that command prompt I can execute @angular/cli commands such as `ng --version` without error. After that global npm module install, within Visual Studio Code, performing the same `ng --version` gives me the error:

> The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I can however within the integrated terminal successfully perform commands such as `npm -v` and `node -v`.

I have the following items in my system environment variables

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

`%AppData%\npm`

Are there Visual Studio Code user or system environment variables I'm missing to allow detection of global npm modules?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: try to change the terminal from powershell to cmd.exe

Comment: Changing default shell to cmd.exe gives me the same errors regarding global npm modules.

Comment: so the problem i think is in the path variable .. check them in the global variables (if there are the path to the npm in AppData Roaming etc etc)

Comment: ```npm install -g @angular/cli``` fixed it for me (also I updated node using npm) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue and use global npm commands in Visual Studio Code by modifying my system environment path variables to position `%AppData%\npm` before `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\` per npm [troubleshooting tips](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/troubleshooting/)

Comment: Please update the link to: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/troubleshooting

Comment: For me, it worked only after killing existing terminal instance/ commands in VS code and then adding new terminal. Cause to outcome ratio is staggering though ;)

Answer (score 88):

Visual Studio Code must be "Run as Administrator" for working Terminal Commands.

Comment: Thanku so much bro..u have saved me.. u r champion for me..

Comment: On my previous laptop (windows 10) the terminal worked without starting VSC as admin. Now on my new laptop (also win 10) it seems to only work when I start VCS as Admin each time. Very annoying...

Comment: @G-Unit same issue.. have u resolved it?

Comment: I solved it, but unfortunatly don't remember how :)

Answer (score 29):

no need to do anything else just follow below steps -

1. right click on my computer (this pc).
2. go to properties.
3. click on advanced system setting.
4. click on environmental variable.
5. select path variable from system variable.
6. click on edit button.
7. add %AppData%\npm and %ProgramFiles%\nodejs\ at top of the list.
   8 click on ok. ok. ok
8. restart your system.
9. after restart open visual studio code as run as administrative mode.
10. Enjoy...............!!!!!

[image]

Comment: This solution worked exactly for me. No need to restart your system though. The ng command started working in VS Code Terminal.

Comment: worked for me. I had some issues updating my NPM packages after windows update and sometimes randomly, after adding these, I don't have any problems so far!

Comment: for me, %AppData%\npm and %ProgramFiles%\nodejs\ these path do not exists. Am I missing something after vs code installation?

Answer (score 6):

Run Visual studio code `as an administrator`. Then type `ng` command. It should work

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you answer a question try to comment your answer a little bit. In this case, as there are some more answers, you should exposed the Cons and Pros of your answer. If not, just make a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Reboot your computer , this worked for me

Comment: I freshly installed Node.js (NPM) and I had to restart my computer also to get NPM to register in my terminal.

Comment: This was also the issue for me. Restarting fixed it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

If you have entered the environment variable and it is still not recognized and if you don't want to reboot your computer because you have so many things running then just reboot your Visual Studio Or Visual Studio Code and then Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) and run

> npm install

Now it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, not even a VS Code Reload command will do this: you must exit all instances of the program.

Comment: exactly. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve the issue by opening the VS Code Terminal and type

> npm install -g @angular/cli

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Wondering why the terminal for VS code behaves differently from the native one.

Comment: @KarthickManoharan It is because many of the environment variables you need to define for windows is predefined there. BTW did you downvote the answer?

Answer (score 2):

1. Run powershell or cmd prompt in admin mode.
2. Check if npm and node commands work (if not, then check environment variables as others have mentioned).
3. Update node using npm [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-
   npm-on-windows]

   - Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
   - npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
   - npm-windows-upgrade
4. Run npm install -g @angular/cli
5. Run ng --version in Visual Studio Code to see if it's now working.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have access to Environmental variable (office machines).

You can try to run command like this:

> `npm run <your angular command>`

it works as well, just need to add **npm run** before ng command

> Example ->  `npm run ng g c shop/cart`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding `%AppData%\npm` to your Path variable made it work for PowerShell and the Command Prompt, it still did not work for the integrated PowerShell in VS Code for me.

When I changed it from `%AppData%\npm` to the actual path **`C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\npm`** where `<USER>` is your user directory, and reopened VS Code it started working.

Answer (score 0):

To me the solution was adding the extensions for npm:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly to all the good advice here, make sure that you have node.js installed on your machine.