# ng not recognized in terminal

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

After installing angular,

```
home@Hannahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % node --version
v16.15.0
home@Hannahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm --version
8.5.5
home@Hannahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli

changed 196 packages, and audited 197 packages in 7s

24 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

ng is not found,

```
home@Hannahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % ng new my-app
zsh: command not found: ng
```

My path is,

```
home@Hannahs-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

What can I do to get ng / angular working through terminal and also through vscode

Comment: Maybe something from here would be a solution for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138138/angular-cli-ng-command-not-found-on-mac-os

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://angular.io/guide/setup-local ?

Answer (score 0):

start a new terminal. As any new thing added to environment variable need a new terminal instance.

Comment: Hey I tried, a new instance and it still is not recognized.

Comment: try ng --version command? check your environment variables? through vscode? allow access to your environment variable to vs code.

Comment: How do I check the environment variables in vscode? How do I allow access to the environment variables?

Comment: right click vs code and click run as administrator or follow this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45355083/10982972

Comment: I am familiar with how to do this on windows but how do I do it on Mac?