# npm 5.4.1 install/uninstall all failing

Tags: node.js, npm

I am on Windows 10. I upgraded my npm by doing a `npm i -g npm`.

However no package is installing or uninstallating. On install it is hanging always on postinstall like this:

> PS C:\Users\Mercurius\Documents\GitHub\catchem-front> npm i --save immutable
>   [            ......] \ postinstall: info lifecycle immutable@3.8.1~postinstall: > immutable@3.8.1

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

On uninstall it hangs/fails on:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd C:\Users\Mercurius\Documents\GitHub\catche
>   PS C:\Users\Mercurius\Documents\GitHub\catchem-front> npm un --save c
>   [            ......] \ postinstall: sill doSerial postinstall 894

This was me trying to run it as administrator in powershell, but same problem. It ends up giving me some `unlink` error and tells me to try admin mode:

[image]

I then got `npm-windows-upgrade` and followed here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520672/1828637

I even downloaded the latest `node` msi installer and upgraded to 8.5 but still getting this hang on postinstall..

However still having this issue. I think I used `npm-windows-upgrade` a long time ago, and they warn not to use `npm i -g npm` anymore, which I just found out, do you think this is the issue?

Comment: Try to use `nvm` to manage the version of node & npm.

Comment: `nvm` doesnt work on windows, I used it succefsully on linux and macs though. Thanks for the idea though @EricWang

Comment: For windows, there is a similar tool written in go. https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: npm 5.4.0 and 5.4.1 just wouldnt work no matter what, i had to reinstall node with and leave the npm version that came with it.

Comment: If you must use windows machine, maybe it's better to create a vm using virtualbox, that's my first choice when working in a company that must use windows as dev machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPM 5.4.0 and 5.4.1 have issues, You have 2 options one is to downgrade the current version

```
npm i -g npm@5.3.0
```

or the following which is to re-install with --no-optional flag which will prevent optional dependencies from being installed which seems to be the problem,

```
npm i -g npm@5.3.0
npm cache clean --force
npm install --no-optional
```

First method will work, second I have not tried it but should work theoretically.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had ended up re-installing with the installer from node's website. I am now currently on 5.4.2 and it seems to work.

Comment: @noitidart hey could you put the exact commands please. I'm stuck unable to install npm. I want npm 5.4.2 with node 8.x installed

Comment: @kRazzyR I actually used the Windows installer from the nodejs.org website, so I had no commands.