# A new version of npm has been installed, but the old one is still being used

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I was shown this when I was installing dependencies for a project:

```
 Update available 5.7.1 → 5.8.0    │
   │       Run npm i npm to update
```

Then I did this:

```
$ npm i npm
npm WARN react-hot-api@0.4.7 requires a peer of react@>=0.11.0 || ^0.14.0-rc but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ npm@5.8.0
added 523 packages from 726 contributors in 12.75s
```

But why is it still the old version?

```
$ npm --version
5.7.1
```

Comment: Depending on how you installed it the first time, you should uninstall the old verison and set the path to the new location

Comment: you should use nvm if you wanted to use multiple nodejs version

Comment: or delete old version and then install new version

Answer (score 5):

> But why is it still the old version?

By default, npm installs packages in the local `node_modules/` directory. Since `npm i npm` is shorthand for `npm install npm`, it will install the latest version of npm locally.

However, when run `npm` in a shell, the shell picks up the `npm` in your `$PATH`, which is probably the global installation.

---

To update the global installation of npm, run:

```
npm install --global npm
```

You'll also probably will want to delete the local installation of npm to reduce bloat:

```
npm uninstall npm
```

See [How can I update Node.js and npm to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions/6237400#6237400) for more information on updating.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference from Robert Baker's answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows),

1. Run PowerShell as Admin
2. Run the following codes:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade`

Note: Do not run `npm i -g npm`. Instead use `npm-windows-upgrade` to update npm going forward. Also if you run the NodeJS installer, it will replace the node version.

I was able to upgrade from 5.6 to 6.7 (latest version from the writing of this comment)