# Cannot find module , Missing modules #557

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm, vue-cli

After `npm install -g @vue/cli@3.0.0-beta.9` ,

I run the command `vue create client`
I get the following output:

```
module.js:557        
    throw err;            
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cmd-shim'    
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)  
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)  
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)  
    at Object.<anonymous>  
 (/Users/atalante/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/linkBin.js:10:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)   
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)   
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)  
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

i tried `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried installing `cmd-shim`? `npm install -g cmd-shim`. Also, have you tried installing the latest version of `@vue/cli`?

Comment: now, i have tried installing cmd-shim and that's worked . Thank u !!

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when there is an issue with either your node or npm installations, Try updating node.js and npm to resolve the issue which has worked for me in the past. This might help in updating npm : [Update NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows)