# npm located in two different directories on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm

I just had a trouble to upgrade my `npm` version from `5.0.0` to `6.4.1` on Windows 10.

What i did was just downloading NodeJS (latest) installer, i.e. `8.12.0` (it includes `npm` `6.4.1`). It was successfully installed, **however** when i did `npm -v` it still on version `5.0.0`, so it only updated the `node` part only.

Then i follow this instruction ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31520672)), basically it uses `npm` package called `npm-windows-upgrade`, at first try it threw a lot of **error**.

Basically i have to do several cycles of NodeJS uninstall, NodeJS reinstall, and executing `npm-windows-upgrade`, after few times it finally succeeded (luck), now my `npm` is at `6.4.1`. **However** when i run `where npm` on terminal it listed **two locations** of my `npm` files:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
```

and this is kind of strange, it should only listing one location, i.e. `C:\Program Files\nodejs\..` but apparently i have `npm` too on `AppData\Roaming` directory, **why is this happening?** **should i delete the second one?**

PS - If i run `where node`, it listed only one location, i.e:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

Comment: can you review the answer? @xcode

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm` is the location for node packages for the current user, while `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` is the installation dir for all users.

See what `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd -v` returns. If it's the same as `npm -v` then you are fine.

You could run node without the installer, in this case `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` would not be in the PATH (for System env variables), however all the global packages would be placed under `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\`. Since npm is a global package, it appers there.

TL;DR No action required.