# I cannot get Node.js to install the current version (Windows)

Tags: npm, npm-install

I ran `npm -v` and it listed a version (I can't remember exactly which) something like 0.6.1.

I ran `npm install nodejs-latest` to try an update my package. It went to version 6.6.0

I unstalled node.js completely, redownloaded and installed from https://nodejs.org/en/

Checked `npm -v` and it returned 6.5.0

I ran this suggestion from stackoverflow: [How can I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows)

It lists out the versions available to install and it only goes up to 6.7.0

I'm totally lost. Why can't I get the current version of node.js on this machine?

Comment: npm != node.js. `node -v`.

Comment: :(   derp ... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm is the Node Package Manager, when you run "npm -v" it will show you the npm version and the "node -v" will show you Node version.

To update npm version you should run *npm install -g npm* .

To update the node version you can download it at the [NodeJs website](https://nodejs.org/en/).
Or you can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows) steps to update.

Comment: I'm embarrassed. Thank you.