# Different NPM version used when generating React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I try to create the starter React [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) app using powershell, I get the below error:

> "You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be boostrapped with an old unsupported version of tools".
>
> "Please update to npm 3 or higher for a better, fully supported experience".

However, my NPM version is 6.11.3 as seen below.

[image]

What I have tried:

- I have ran powershell as admin [as answered in this question and restart.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows)
- I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Nodejs completely.

Comment: Try searching for some older versions of node that may come with other packages by typing { where node } in CMD to locate all versions

Comment: C:\Users\nyl2k>where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Answer (score 4):

So after an extra hour digging around, I saw a few posts with similar (but not exactly) the same issue. I decided to install Yarn and install with that. 
After install, I ran `yarn cache clean` and ran `npx create-react-app your-app` and it worked. Sorry for bothering you all.

Comment: Solved my problem too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I'm running WSL with ubuntu, and `yarn cache clear` didn't work, but I noticed a node modules directory created in the project. I think it was messing with the node version so I deleted it. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cleaning cache and/or reinstalling everything, I removed the node_modules from the root (current) folder.