# Why I can't install React and uninstall create-react-app in my system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have tried so many ways. But I can't find any solution. The problem is I can't install ReactJS in my system. Here is the message I get when complete my installation process.

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an
>   outdated version of create-react-app. Please note that global installs
>   of create-react-app are no longer supported.

I cleaned the cache. I also saw it with a fresh node even wanted to try uninstalling the create-react-app. But if I do, I get this message.

[image]

I manually deleted this log and it didn't work.

Can anyone suggest me any solution?

> Update: Actually these two problems are solved when I manually deleted
>   the cache from the AppData\Roaming\npm (temp) directory.
>
> Thanks Everyone

Comment: command you are running to create-react-app ??

Comment: You probably need `sudo`...

Comment: @FMCorz On a windows machine?

Comment: Whoops... had not noticed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been getting error to uninstall create-react-app and install react in my windows system. I tried to delete the cache by this command `npm cache clean`. But it didn't work for me. Finally, I came up with a solution. Though this may not be the best solution.

**These two problems are solved when I manually deleted the cache from the AppData\Roaming\npm and npm-cache(temp) directory.**

Note: I tried to install a new version of the node which overrides the previous one. But it did not remove the cache.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: This worked for me, although my cache was in %AppData\Local\npm-cache.

Answer (score 13):

For me the following worked to uninstall create-react-app:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app    
npm cache clean --force    
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Comment: it only worked for me after running npx clear-npx-cache .. thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it only worked for me after the `npx clear-npx-cache` step!

Answer (score 9):

in Linux, I solved it by going to home directory/.npm

then delete _cacache and _npx with "rm -rf foldername"

Comment: This one is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 6):

The latest react version has removed support for generating projects from global install.

> npm install -g create-react-app will not work.

If you get any errors about missing templates or how a global Create React App install is no longer supporting, you likely need to remove the global package from your system:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app

Manually remove from the dir also (Mac devices)

- rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app

The only supported method for generating a project is now:

> npx create-react-app myapp

Another situation is if you have not updated react then please follow the below steps:

- Clean the cache.

> npm cache clean --force

or

> Goto %appdata%\npm-cache and check if the directory is clean or not.
>   If not, delete all file from the directory manually.

Now try create-react-app yourAppName

Comment: Removing the dir worked for me thanks:
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this issue until i tried to uninstall create-react-app from the source. I found where it was installed and realized that because i was using NVM, the version of create-react-app that my system was picking up was from another version of node that i was not using at the time.

So i ran

```
nvm list
```

then went through each version of node i had on my system using:

```
nvm use <version>
```

then to remove create-react-app i ran :

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

for each version i had installed

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Removing manually: ```cd ~/.nvm/versions/node``` find your unused node versions and ```rm -rf vX.Y.Z/``` Then ```rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app``` Then ```nvm cache clear``` worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (Windows user)

```
npm uninstall create-react-app    
npm cache clean --force    
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you fixed this issue, but this worked for me:

```sh
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then

```sh
npx clear-npx-cache
```

```sh
npm install -g create-react-app
```

OR

```sh
npx create-react-app <project_name>
```

Comment: npx clear-npx-cache worked for me

Answer (score 1):

So, I know this has been answered several times, but after attempting each of the suggested solutions I've only found this one to work for me. First, I uninstalled the global create-react-app.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And then removed the cache. Yet, it still was not working. Turns out, I had a non-global install of create-react-app in the directory that I keep my projects.

```
npm uninstall create-react-app
```

After running the command without the -g all was well. If nothing else works, this may be someone's solution if they're experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Linux user, make sure to use sudo before the command, otherwise it will show you the same error.

This is how I fixed it for myself

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

I had your same issue and I fix it by updating npm to the latest version.

In my case, my npm version was 7.0.15
You can test your using: `npm -v`

If you are using Mac or Linux give the next command:
`sudo npm install -g npm`

And now try again with the new version. In my case it prompted:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

I clicked 'enter' without giving an answer and now create-react-app works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had to first unistall Create React App using the command ->

 npm uninstall -g create-react-app.
Then I installed

 install create-react-app. -> when I tried without this it never worked
After that I created my app with

 npx create-react-app my-app

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

[screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKHSe.png)

I was facing the same issue. In spite removing react-app, I was not able to install react app again.
I tried to install the react app using `npx create-react-app my-app` and `npm init react-app my-app` but both didn't work.
I later tried installing using `yarn create react-app my-app` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

try this

Comment: I'm getting the same result as I got in create-react-app

Comment: refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall create-react-app -

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then try -

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Sorry to say, still got the same message. 

"A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported."

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
npx create-react-app my-app 
cd my-app 
npm start
```

Make sure you are installing the last version of nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Goto %appdata%\npm\node_modules,

- Delete the create-react-app folder
- Navigate out of the node_modules folder, then delete the create-react-app file and create-react-app.cmd

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but was unable to modify the npm cache due to account restrictions, the best solution was to install and run at the same time.

The below will install the latest and run it at the CWD

```
npx create-react-app@latest . --template typescript
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me so I changed Node version from `16.0` to `14.16.1` and it worked immediately. I used `nvm` for change, and it is not the first time I have to juggle back and forth with Node versions on my M1 Mac.