# Is there really no straightforward way to update node and npm on windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

Have spent far too long on this, about to give up.

I know you can go to the official website to update Node but I would like to be able to do it through the command line.

Anyway, when I do `npm install npm@latest -g`

I get

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path D:\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Refusing to delete D:\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: D:\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I found another solution but did not work for me:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

This works up to this far, then it asks me for which version I want to install. I select it, then I get:

```
You wanted to install npm 6.14.5, but the installed version is 6.13.4.

A common reason is an attempted "npm install npm" or "npm upgrade npm". As of today, the only solution is to completely uninstall and then reinstall Node.js. For a small tutorial, please see https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade#usage.

Please consider reporting your trouble to https://aka.ms/npm-issues.
```

I am almost dead. Any help appreciated!

Comment: On windows I think your best bet is using the installers from the website. On Linux you could use your OS package manager or nvm - there may be a Windows version of nvm so that could be worth looking into

Comment: Thanks Michael. Alright, for Node, I can go to the official website. However what about npm?

Comment: When upgrading node, you'll also get a newer version of npm. However to upgrade it between node versions on Linux I just do `npm i -g npm` - based on your question this doesn't appear to be an option on windows unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 
[How can I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows)
or

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: Think the op is referring to a windows system

Comment: No worries. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Enjoy the site.

Comment: FYI that question is now locked and the top rated answer (same as yours) is to use a package that hasn't seen a release in years, and whose owner recently archived the repository.  We need a new "how should I use node/NPM on Windows in 2021" question, I think.