# Unable to upgrade to latest version of npm after installing recent Node version

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-update, npm-version

The current version of npm installed in my pc is `4.6.1`.

I want to upgrade to the latest version or any other version `>= 5.2.0`. But when try to do so, I am getting these errors (as displayed below). Please suggest me a solution.

**Error:**

> ```
> C:\Users\xxx>node -v
> v14.5.0
>
> C:\Users\xxx>npm -v
> 4.6.1
>
> C:\Users\xxx>npm -g install @latest
>
> npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\xxx\@latest
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\xxx\@latest
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\xxx\@latest'
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T15_02_38_917Z-debug.log
>
> C:\Users\xxx>npm upgrade
>
> npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T15_02_45_863Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: How do you trying to upgrade it? Which command are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update npm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows) And make sure you ron the latest LTS release of nodejs

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this problem?