# Gulp Watch only run once

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using this Gulp Watch sample: https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#starting-tasks-on-events.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var batch = require('gulp-batch');

gulp.task('build', function () { console.log('Working!'); });

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch('**/*.js', batch(function () {
        gulp.start('build');
    }));
});
```

When I run it on my Windows 8 machine, it only runs the first time I change a file:

```
C:\test>gulp watch
[08:40:21] Using gulpfile C:\test\gulpfile.js
[08:40:21] Starting 'watch'...
[08:40:21] Finished 'watch' after 2.69 ms
[08:40:31] Starting 'build'...
Working!
[08:40:31] Finished 'build' after 261 µs
```

Next time nothing happens. Why?

Comment: Did you change any file? Because you when you execute gulp watch, it is watching the files. When you then change a file, the function in watch gets fired.

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm not clear enough. I'm changing files, but `watch` is only executed the first time I change a file. E.g. if I start `gulp watch`, change something in my *.js file and save it, watch is running. If I then change something else in the same file and save it again, then watch is not running. The `gulp watch` process is still running, but nothing happens.

Comment: If you still want to use the `gulp-batch` the correct usage is to have a `done` callback there: `done` - is callback for your function signal to batch, that you are done. So:  `gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch('**/*.js', batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('build');
  done();
    }));
});`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you read the documentation closely, you see the following phrase:

> You can pass plain callback, that will be called on every event **or wrap it in gulp-batch to run it *once***

So, that's basically the deal with `gulp-batch`. To constantly watch it, just remove the batch call:

```
gulp.task('build', function (done) { 
    console.log('Working!'); 
    done();
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch('app/*.js', function () {
        gulp.start('build');
    });
});
```

(and add the 'done' callback to `build` to let Gulp know when you're finished).

Btw... I'm not sure, but I think `gulp-watch` is meant to not only watch files, but also directly returning a vinyl object. So actually using the built-in `gulp.watch` should have the same effect:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js', ['build']);
});
```

Comment: Old post but lemme quote something again from what @ddprrt said, 
`"(and add the 'done' callback to build to let Gulp know when you're finished)."` 
And that nearly made me hit my head on the wall for hours. Thanks man

Comment: starting with gulp 4, the `done` callback is a must, it seems....thx!

Comment: Hi @ddprrt it seems that when two dev working on the same system then other dev subsequent(first working) cntrl + s not detected through the gulp. Even though it works for the same system. Any idea?

Answer (score 23):

For me it was adding a "return" to the task:

```
gulp.task('styles', function(){
 return gulp.src('css/styles.css')
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Comment: ...or a passing and calling a callback: `(cb) => { something(); cb(); }`

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be [known issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/84)
I had the same problem and used the same as ddprrt. The difference was using directory [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (wildcard) as apposed to absolute path.

I changed this:

```
 gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('sass/shortcutcss/*.scss', ['sass'])
 });
```

to this:

```
 gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
 });
```

Comment: Same problem and same solution here. Maybe open an issue on github about this would be a good ideia.

Comment: I had the same problem and resolved it adding the wildcard directory /**/*.scss, now it work

Comment: Looks like the issue is still relevant. /**/ wildcard dir resolved my issue.

Comment: I had to use a `**` wildcard for directories and a `*` wildcard for file names. I couldn't use the exact directory and file name, strange!

Comment: This also occurs even if just one of the paths is in that format, e.g. `'./css/*.css', './css/*.scss', './css/*/*.scss'`

Answer (score 1):

This problem made me crazy for a weekend. I tried all:

- Add done()-Event
- Rename/Touch/Clear target CSS
- Be more specific with the filepaths

But the (reason for this problem and) the solution was so easy that I felt pathetic after that:

Just [update your nodejs installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js), mine was 0.12.x! No wonder that this doesn't worked.

After that the watch event works again. Sometimes it goes wrong again, too. But in this cases just save your file a second time and it get recognized. (I think `foundation/gulp watch` checks for changes to fast and while your file get replaced with the new uploaded one)

Answer (score 0):

Long story:
For me it did not work for long time. All seems to be set right but run only once.

But suddenly I started with parcel js on another project and same thing happened with their builtn watch. So I looked for the answer and I found out that problem was with my **Vim** settings.

Answer what helped me is this one from @acobster https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435197/2686510

In short:
Update `.vimrc` by adding `set backupcopy=yes`