# parcel watch only detects first file change

Tags: parceljs

I have the following in `./js/parcel/build-js.js` (it is more or less a simplification of exactly what the [API docs example](https://parceljs.org/api.html#bundler) does, except that it takes an optional `--watch` argument):

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');
const path = require('path');

const watch = process.argv.indexOf('--watch') > 0;

if (watch) console.log('Watching files...');

(async function bundleJs() {
  const jsBundler = new Bundler(path.join(__dirname, '../src/common.js'), {
    watch,
    hmr: false,
  });

  jsBundler.on('bundled', () => {
    console.log('bundled!');
  });

  const bundle = await jsBundler.bundle();

  console.log('done');
})();
```

When I run `node js/parcel/build-js.js --watch`, it detects the first change to `src/common.js` and prints:

```
Watching files...
✨  Built in 585ms.
bundled!
done
```

This is as I'd expect. When I edit and save `src/common.js`, it sees that and then the total output becomes (`done` gets deleted):

```
Watching files...
✨  Built in 585ms.
bundled!
✨  Built in 86ms.
bundled!
```

**But after that, no file changes are detected.** I make changes and save but it just sits there, producing no more output or updating the build. Why only once?

Note: If I do `strace node js/parcel/build-js.js --watch`, it seems to just sit on an unfinished `epoll_wait(3,`, which I guess means it's waiting for something, but maybe watching the wrong file...

**Edit: Versions!**

- parcel-bundler: 1.12.3
- node: 10.15.1
- Ubuntu 18.04

**Edit: using `parcel watch`**

This appears to be a system-wide thing for me. I did `yarn globals add parcel` (which also installed 1.12.3), and now watching *any* JS file with `parcel watch path/to/file.js` does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be a conflict between Parcel's change detection and the default Vim setup. From the [Hot Module Replacement docs](https://parceljs.org/hmr.html#safe-write):

> Some text editors and IDE's have a feature called safe write that basically prevents data loss, by taking a copy of the file and renaming it when saved.
>
> When using Hot Module Reload (HMR) this feature blocks the automatic detection of file updates, to disable safe write use the options provided below:

I added `set backupcopy=yes` to my `.vimrc` and it started working.

The solution for other editors is documented there as well.

Comment: It doesn't work with Neovim (using v0.4.0). Is there something else to do?