# npm install Error in Laravel

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to do

`npm install`.

But encountered the following errors:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.2.3.tgz
    npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.7
    npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/parse-asn1/-/parse-asn1-3.0.1.tgz
    npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\Jil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\88935c05-cache-inherits-2-0-1-package-tgz.lock'
    File exists: C:\Users\Jil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\88935c05-cache-inherits-2-0-1-package-tgz.lock
    Move it away, and try again.

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\nom5\laravel
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Jil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\88935c05-cache-inherits-2-0-1-package-tgz.lock
    npm ERR! code EEXIST
    npm ERR! errno 47
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

node version: `v0.10.33`
nmp version: `npm@1.4.28`

Comment: update npm, node and try again with sudo.

Comment: @emrah It says `npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\Jil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\57f43880-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: C:\Users\Jil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\57f43880-adable-stream-1-0-33-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.`

But I checked the path and can't find any item.

Comment: they are hidden by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js