# Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: javascript

This error pops up on my JS console in the browser, and I'm not sure how to interpret the message. Can anyone describe what causes this?

Thanks

Comment: if you use node.js, you just need to update your node to latest version

Answer (score 136, accepted):

This means that you must declare strict mode by writing `"use strict"` at the beginning of the file or the function to use block-scope declarations.

EX:

```
function test(){
    "use strict";
    let a = 1;
}
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, added "use strict" at the top of my function but still doesn't works... Any idea? Thanks

Comment: This might be node.js app.

Comment: @FarzadCyrus it doesn't work for me either - I'm using the chrome console 48.0.2564.103 m

Comment: @FarzadCyrus got it working using (function() { "use strict"; })(); in the console

Comment: @kayakpim Yes mate, for some reason it wasn't working initially, but after restarting my browser it worked fine! Not sure what was it causing the browser to behave like that... but surely wasn't to do with the script itself! It sometimes happens to the JS engines... hope it helps...
Have you tried it on jsFiddle or CodePen? Cheers

Comment: I'm getting this in a node app, how to fix?

Comment: For node it's node --use_strict

Comment: I'm using node v7.2.0 and use strict isn't needed for let anymore

Comment: My problem was with cordova. I updated with 'n' to the latest version of node, now it works fine. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/530197

Comment: What you say doesn't work. I have `"use strict"` everywhere in my files and still have the issue

Comment: I got the same issue for my node js app (express). I used "use strict" at beginning and problem solved.

Comment: i tried this with use strict, but i got many errors, instead i removed let and used var instead that solved my issue

Comment: Too me worked only adding the `;` at the end, which means `"use strict";`