# npm installation shown can n't call method 'localeCompare' of undefined

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, nodemailer

First i installed nodemailer then it shown did n't configure correctly.After that i updated it up-to nodemailer 0.7.1 then it shown can't find mimelib module.Then i try to re-install nodemailer again then i show below error.why is that ..? when i try to install another library.It may occur.

```html
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-15-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "nodemailer"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5

npm ERR! Cannot call method 'localeCompare' of undefined
```

I tried using sudo key word and try to install globally and updated all the packages but it does n't helpful.still same.

Comment: You should consider adding this as an issue in nodemailer's github repo. Maybe they can help.

Comment: i tried it.but i couldn't find solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the version of node you're using is too old.
I had this issue and used n to run multiple versions of node.

Here's a link to options on how to [upgrade node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js)