# protractor executing config.js not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, protractor

I installed protractor using

```
npm install -g protractor
```

and then I executed this command:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

next, I started it, it works fine and I see this message:

`INFO - Selenium Server is up and running`
 The problem is that when I try

```
protractor config.js
```

it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:155
            throw e;
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

.

I thought this is because protractor needs `node version > 4.~` . So I checked mine I found `0.10.25` so I tried

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 4.4.0
```

THe installation worked and when I check `node -v` again it's still `0.10.25`

Any help pleaase?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to *update this node link* ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855966/771848)):

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/4.4.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```