# Installation of Angularjs using npm install - ERROR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

I am currently trying to build and install angular.js as per the instructions here: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute#Installing-dependencies

However when I reach the stage where I am to install node.js dependencies I get the following warning: (There are more errors too but the install continued after them so they were not available on the console).

```
WARN engine is-buffer@1.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
```

This warning is strange however as I was under the impression I had installed node version 0.12 anyway.

The errors in the log file read as follows:

```
  147687 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry library/fn/number/virtual/to-precision.js
147688 error weird error 127
147689 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

...

```
    147732 error tar pack Error reading /home/dimitri/tmp/npm-6229-5eEV6QxH/1470304972279-0.6845361003652215/package
147733 silly lockFile 0e9c507f-72279-0-6845361003652215-package tar:///home/dimitri/tmp/npm-6229-5eEV6QxH/1470304972279-0.6845361003652215/package
147734 silly lockFile 0e9c507f-72279-0-6845361003652215-package tar:///home/dimitri/tmp/npm-6229-5eEV6QxH/1470304972279-0.6845361003652215/package
```

...

```
    error Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/dimitri/tmp/npm-6229-5eEV6QxH/1470304951838-0.9155439815949649/package/src/core/longstacktraces/longstacktraces.js'
147757 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
147757 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
147757 error or email it to:
147757 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
147758 error System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
147759 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
147760 error cwd /home/dimitri/angular.js
147761 error node -v v0.10.25
147762 error npm -v 1.3.10
147763 error path /home/dimitri/tmp/npm-6229-5eEV6QxH/1470304951838-0.9155439815949649/package/src/core/longstacktraces/longstacktraces.js
147764 error fstream_path /home/dimitri/tmp/npm-6229-5eEV6QxH/1470304951838-0.9155439815949649/package/src/core/longstacktraces/longstacktraces.js
147765 error fstream_type File
147766 error fstream_class FileWriter
147767 error code ENOENT
147768 error errno 34
147769 error fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
147769 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

...

Comment: Can you run `node -v` or `node --version`? You should also check [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5542) which includes various fixes mostly regarding the npm cache.

Comment: When i enter them at command prompt nothing happens

Comment: Have you installed node? https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: I believe so, use "apt-get install node" and it seemed to work anyway

Comment: @AlexD If i download it from that site, how do I then install it? I have the tar.gz file and extracted it...

Comment: Have a read of this. I suggest using `nvm` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-to-update-node-js

Comment: @alexi2 I have downloaded nvm, what command do i use to make it?

Comment: `nvm install node` see docs here https://github.com/creationix/nvm