# How do I make my environment use current(ish) node?

Tags: node.js, version, nvm, node-sass

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: 
OS X 64-bit with Node.js 4.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
```

I get that. Sort of. Except:   `node -v => v6.9.2`

So what is it getting my current environment from? I'm using `nvm` to manage node versions.. but I'm getting conflicting information about what version of node I'm running.

I also followed [these instructions to upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/530585)

How to I just use v6.9.2 everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

NVM manages node versions separately by shell and doesn't persist a set version. [You can set the default version](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#listing-versions) by using `nvm alias default v6.9.2`