# Need help regarding update of node.js

Tags: node.js

how to update node.js

running command 
sudo npm install n -g but getting the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgjw.png

Comment: Quote the error message. Don't show us a picture of the text.

Comment: It's probably easier to [follow these steps](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) if you want to install a more recent version of Node.js on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from another post: [How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)

"Use Node Version Manager (NVM)

It's a Bash script that lets you download and manage different versions of node. Full source code is here.

There is a separate project for nvm for Windows: github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows"