# How to update the Node.js in windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, nodes

After I upgraded the ionic CLI, I have error when I do a `ionic serve`.

The error is

```
ERR: Your Node.js version is v5.11.1. Please update to the latest Node 6 LTS version (or latest Node).
```

What is the command that I can upgrade to Node 6 LTS without redownload the Node.js installer?

Comment: Re-download and install it?

Comment: Use a package manager like chocolatey for Windows

Comment: I want to avoid to download it again. That is why I want to know if it can be upgrade with command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NVM Windows Version (Node Version Manager) - be aware its a separate version from Mac / Linux

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

More info you can check out this one :

[How do I update Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)

```
nvm install node
```

Comment: It would be great if you would include some content of the links, like 'Install NVM Windows for easier management of installed node versions' or something like that. Otherwise when those links won't work anymore your answer wouldn't be of any value anymore.

Comment: @flob I see , I will update my answer ! Thank your for the advice

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to update your node in case some impacts might occur to your projects, the most effective way to tackle this is to reinstall your ionic CLI in command prompt by operating: "npm uninstall -g ionic" and npm install -g ionic@.... You might need to switch earlier version of ionic so as to match with your cordova or some other App package.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaBgm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just download and install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/. It will detect your current installation version and upgrade it if necessary.