# Error is triggered when i am running npm init

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, bootstrap-4

**Code MODULE_NOT_FOUND**

In project folder running the npm init this error show.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsJ5K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting all of the dependencies of your project and reinstalling node with the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: I am getting same error after npm init

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083351/node-module-not-found

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling node?

Comment: I resolve this issue.