# I am having an Error in running a node.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am new to Node.js and I am trying to run my test files via Node.js. I am simply typing `node .\tut63.js` but it is showing the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User11\Desktop\Complete Web Developement Bootcamp\tut63.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)    
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I am simply running a `console.log("HelloWorld");` as my `test.js` file

Comment: Can you provide the file contents? Your question is not meaningful if you try running `tut63.js` and your file name is `test.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is called "test.js", right? Try running:

```
node test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file name is test.js then you need to navigate to the directory where your project is in the terminal. Then run node test.js. Hop it works

Answer (score -1):

Could also be related to a broken node installation. Try reinstalling it completely. You can also try to remove npm completely at `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` before reinstalling everything (related, but not Windows: [Node MODULE_NOT_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083351/node-module-not-found))

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to install the npm packages:

```
npm install
```